# Using remote host as working directory, git extensions

Tags: git, git-extensions

Instead of cloning a repository and developing & testing locally, our project has to be hosted on the server and tested there, due to licensing restrictions (operate on particular domain, within a specific path, specific IP allowed, etc)

Therefore we cannot setup local test environments, we have to use a central repository and use that as a sort of "remote working directory"

The development team would like to use [`git extensions (gui)`](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)

Is there anyway of setting up git extensions to open a remote as a working directory and act on it, instead of a local one? When any changes are made to the server test repository, they should appear in the staging area.

Please see the picture [below (large)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbcl5.jpg) for example

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need that, use some kind of remote desktop software, log in to the remote box and work there.

You might say "but in that case, only one person could develop at a time". That's right. And that would also be the case if you use a remote directory as working directory.
Or at least: it should be.
Having multiple users work on the **same** working copy doesn't sound feasible to me.

Comment: I completely agree, it's far from the ideal solution but changing the software we use on the website isn't feasible at the moment. We're stuck with it's and the licensing restrictions. So unfortunately we can effectively only have one working directory. I thought it might be possible just to have git extensions work all commands on the SSH session, not locally.

Comment: +1. If you aren't allowed to pull any source code at all to a local machine, then you can't edit or compile locally. So what you have isn't a revision control system issue at all.