# VSS to Clearcase transition, appending comments

Tags: clearcase

Is there a way to perform a Clearcase checkin where the checkin comments are appended directly into the source file? This is like VSS does.

Please, no debates on whether this is a good or bad thing to do, I have zero influence on these matters here.

I need to have checkin data including the date, user, and comments appended (by clearcase) to the end of the file as in VSS.

Is there a cleartool command option for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Martin is right.
There is no "command" to do a "keyword substitution," or "keyword expansion" (which is useful for simple [Revision System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056912/source-control-vs-revision-control/1056947#1056947), but can be source of [trouble for Version System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645424#645424))

You can find more for [**RCS keyword extension** here](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/cgi-bin/cmwiki/view/CM/BasicClearCase#1.2.5).
Your request does require a type manager avoiding the merge conflicts by interposing itself between the file and the real type manager, removing all RCS keywords.

---

The article "[ClearCase keyword substitutions merge manager](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/1213_diebolt/)" involves:

- a trigger (`keyword_subst.pl`)
- a new type manager (keyed_text_file_delta)
- a new new element type
- the `chtype` over any element you want to have keyword substitution on.
- a preop trigger on the checkin operation tied to this new element type

... a lot of work, but still doable I guess.

As mentioned in the article "Line of source cannot be bigger then 8192 characters.": if one line pass that length, it has to be treated as binary file and can no longer be a candidate for that type manager.

---

Note: the proposed solution [has been reported as not very efficient](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=221105).

> - it is published on "Developerworks" and as such unsupported.
> - The triggers' code itself was probably someone's attempt at learning Perl,
> - it is hard to make it work on Unix
> - is applied by default to text file (not xml or html files)
> - it **does not support comment** (which is what you requested in the first place). You need to amend the script to add `%c` (comment) to a `$Log$` field.

As mentioned (just put here for information):

> There are other ways to do what you want without adding the information into the ClearCase versions!
>
> - If "information as file content" IS NOT required then produce a detailed metadata manifest file.
> - If "information as file content" IS required then add a build step that hijacks these "keyword substitution" files and adds the relevant content - just don't checkin the files afterwards!

Comment: Yes, not as simple as I hoped. Thanks for the quick responses, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to write your own ClearCase trigger to perform the desired keyword substitution. By searching the net I found an [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/1213_diebolt/index.html).