# How do I enable the ident string for a Git repository?

Tags: git, ident

How do I enable `ident $Id$` on files in a Git repository?

Answer (score 43):

***Summary:*** The recommended way of embedding version information in a product is to use the **build system** for that; see below for details and alternate approaches.

---

In Git (and I think usually also in other VCS systems with atomic commits) there is no such thing like *version of a **single file***.

Git does support on-demand expansion of `$Id:$` keyword, but:

1. It is done **on request** only. You have to specify (perhaps using globbing pattern) that a file (or a set of files) has an `ident` [attribute](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#%5Ftt%5Fident%5Ftt) set (in '.gitattributes' file in tree, or in '.git/info/attributes' for local repository settings).
2. It expands to **the SHA-1 of file contents** (or to be more exact to `$Id:<sha-1 of blob>$`). The reason for this choice is that Git does not touch files that have not changed during branch switching or rewinding; if '$Id:$' expanded to revision info it would require to update *every* version-controlled file e.g. when switching branches.

Git supports quite a wide set of `$Format:...$` placeholders which expands to commit information (e.g. `$Format:%H$` replaced by a commit hash) but:

1. Expansion is done **only when running [git archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html)**, in its output file.
2. It is done **on request**, controlled via `export-subst` attribute.

The recommended way of embedding version information is to do it via the **build system** (in a build stage); see for example Git [Makefile](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Makefile;hb=HEAD) and [GIT-VERSION-GEN](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;hb=HEAD) script used by Makefile in the Git web interface for the git.git repository.

You can however (ab)use a clean/smudge filter driver (via `filter` attribute) to get CVS-like keyword expansion, expanding keywords on checkout, and cleaning them up on entering contents to the repository.

Comment: filter driver would be really great if it actually had any power.
As of know it only seems to get filename as a parameter, that is even less than ident filter, getting BLOB SHA1 as a parameter.

If we could pass `$Format:...$` to filter driver command line - that would make it all much better. And that should start with text file charset...

Comment: There is no such thing as a version of a single file, but there is such a thing as the state of all the files at any given time. that state is represented by a hash.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: yes, the state of all files can be represented by the SHA-1 hash of the top tree object of the project, but it is something different from SHA-1 hash of the blob object, i.e. of the file contents.

Comment: If there would be no version of a single file, then you would also be unable to retrieve a version of a bunch of files!

Answer (score 19):

You can do this by adding a pattern for which files you want this functionality followed by `ident` in the `.gitattributes` file. This will replace $Id$ with $Id:<40-digit SHA>$ on checkout of the file. Notice though that it won't give you a revision number of the file as in CVS/SVN.

Example:

```
$ echo '*.txt ident' >> .gitattributes
$ echo '$Id$' > test.txt
$ git commit -a -m "test"

$ rm test.txt
$ git checkout -- test.txt
$ cat test.txt
```

Link to [gitattributes(5) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_tt_ident_tt)

Comment: I just played around with this and as far as I can tell this gives only a SHA for a specific file, not an $Id$ for the entire repository.

Comment: What about `%Format%`?

Comment: Dear readers, note that in the above command line snippet, the ''rm test.txt'' is critical. A checkout operation on an existing file will not add the commit hash to it.

Answer (score 2):

Git's ident does not do what $Id$ does in other versioning systems. As a kludge, use RCS along with git: RCS for individual file revisions and git to checkpoint the project as a whole. As I said, this is a kludge but it does kinda make sense (sometimes for some things).

Answer (score 2):

[Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%C4%99bski) suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796675/6309) (more than 10 years ago ):

> You can however (ab)use a clean/smudge filter driver (via filter attribute) to get CVS-like keyword expansion, expanding keywords on checkout, and cleaning them up on entering contents to the repository.

The criticism is (by [Arioch 'The](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976391/arioch-the) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/how-do-i-enable-the-ident-string-for-a-git-repository/1796675#comment20847388_1796675))

> filter driver would be really great if it actually had any power.
>   **As of know it only seems to get *only* filename as a parameter: that is even less than `ident` filter, which gets the BLOB SHA1 as a parameter**.

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), git content filters are powerless no more!

Git 2.27 provides **more information** (e.g. the object of the tree-ish in which the blob being converted appears, in addition to its path, which has already been given) to **smudge/clean conversion filters**.

See [commit 0c0f8a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c0f8a7f28672fa323312fbba394e5a9949b2aad), [commit 4cf76f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cf76f6bbf8b4d7d32c7c6aec0576959c6accb63), [commit 3f26785](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f267856243693676c04b4d6dfa1e22de62e407a), [commit dfc8cdc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfc8cdc6772a05db4ed64c45df3fe2defdae7eb3), [commit 13e7ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13e7ed6a3a0ecd5d50b7bba2d86ce9d88494fa9b), [commit c397aac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c397aac02f9f97976f675115aa5df6ca01e26d59), [commit ab90eca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab90ecae992e44e3e8303f143ad858608acabcf5) (16 Mar 2020), and [commit a860476](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8604766de8136d78944053aadd74a8c1c87aea9) (10 Mar 2020) by [brian m. carlson (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4e4baee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e4baee3f44da26a5eaab27c76d597b04fef5259), 27 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`convert`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab90ecae992e44e3e8303f143ad858608acabcf5): permit passing additional metadata to filter processes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> There are a variety of situations where a filter process can make use of some additional metadata.
>
> **For example, some people find the ident filter too limiting and would like to include the commit or the branch in their smudged files**.
>
> This information isn't available during checkout as HEAD hasn't been updated at that point, and it wouldn't be available in archives either.
>
> Let's add a way to pass this metadata down to the filter.
>
> We pass the blob we're operating on, the treeish (preferring the commit over the tree if one exists), and the ref we're operating on.
>
> Note that we won't pass this information in all cases, such as when renormalizing or when we're performing diffs, since it doesn't make sense in those cases.
>
> The data we currently get from the filter process looks like the following:
>
> ```
> command=smudge
> pathname=git.c
> 0000
> ```
>
> With this change, we'll get data more like this:
>
> ```
> command=smudge
> pathname=git.c
> refname=refs/tags/v2.25.1
> treeish=c522f061d551c9bb8684a7c3859b2ece4499b56b
> blob=7be7ad34bd053884ec48923706e70c81719a8660
> 0000
> ```
>
> There are a couple things to note about this approach.
>
> For operations like checkout, treeish will always be a commit, since we cannot check out individual trees, but for other operations, like archive, we can end up operating on only a particular tree, so we'll provide only a tree as the treeish.
>
> Similar comments apply for refname, since there are a variety of cases in which we won't have a ref.

And:

> ### [`convert`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c397aac02f9f97976f675115aa5df6ca01e26d59): provide additional metadata to filters
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> Now that we have the codebase wired up to pass any additional metadata to filters, let's collect the additional metadata that we'd like to pass.
>
> **The two main places we pass this metadata are checkouts and archives**.
>   In these two situations, reading HEAD isn't a valid option, since HEAD isn't updated for checkouts until after the working tree is written and archives can accept an arbitrary tree.
>
> In other situations, HEAD will usually reflect the refname of the branch in current use.
>
> We pass a smaller amount of data in other cases, such as [`git cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file), where we can really only logically know about the blob.