# Is there a hook which updates $Id$ in files on clone/pull?

Tags: git, githooks, keyword-expansion

I have a bare (remote) GIT repository with the several users blessed to commit there. On repository clone/pull I want that each source file which contains magic `$Id:$` is expanded to smth. like: `$Id: <name-of-last-committer> <data>`.

It'd be amazing if this expanded/collapsed magic string would not affect on file modification state.

I suppose it is done via hooks. I wonder if there are any ready-to-use such hooks? Or how my task with `$Id` can be solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the section of Pro Git on keyword expansion - I'm sure you can adapt that solution to your needs:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion

Comment: Yes, it seems exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/how-do-i-enable-ident-string-for-git-repos

Answer (score 0):

I use the pre-commit script to alter the $Id:$ tag. It fills out the whole thing with current information. As for the version number, all I do is add one to it. So 1.012 becomes 1.013. The current time and date as well as the current user are added to the tag.