# Django: Get the git revision number of the current project

Tags: django, git, revision

For my django project, I need to read the current git revision number of my project that powers the site, assuming the project is the root dir of the git repository.

This way I will be keeping my css and js pages always up to date as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/app.css?v46">
```

Where 46 is the revision number.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, sorry for not *answering* your question but there are a couple of points you might want to note:

1. Git doesn't have *revision numbers* (okay, maybe it does. Read comments below)
2. If you do this, your site will refresh it's cache even if you make a minor change in a single unrelated file (for example some database logic, totally irrelevant to the actual `.css` file served out to clients)
3. Which makes it a *bad* idea.
4. You could however use the `last-modified` filesystem property for the same (`os.path.getmtime("path.to.file")`)

Comment: +1, although I do need to point out that git *does* have revision numbers, however, they are not sequential. They are also inconvenient for humans, because they are large hexadecimal strings.

Comment: @Arafangion They aren't quite revision *numbers* are they? ;)

Comment: I'mma let you finish, but hexadecimal strings are numbers, they just have a different base (16) </impropermemeuse>

Comment: thanks guys for backing me up, we should respect all numbers, regardless of their base!

Comment: Oh, the technicalities. What's the correct name, though? AFAIK it's called a revision hash.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to distinguish revision numbers from commit ID's;  The difference is very obvious when you use a SCM that uses both, like mercurial;  the revision number increases monotinically, is convenient for humans but is local to the individual repo; where the sha1 is independent of commit history and cryptographically strong;  they are both useful, but almost never for the same things.  I don't think either is that good for what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into projects which take care of this problem for you, like django-mediagenerator:
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-mediagenerator

No need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a templatetag to my django project:

in proj/templatetags, added version.py:

```
from django import template
import time
import os

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def version_date():
    return time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime('../.git')))
```

Then, in my base.html, adding:

```
{% load version %}
<span class='version'>Last Updated: {% version_date %}</span>
```

You could tweak it to use a version num if you choose based on date/time, then append to your stylesheets/js files.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think, you don't want to use tip changeset ID in parameter, see note 2 of @aviral-dasgupta answer, but id of last-change-this-file changeset in order to resresh cache only when file changed
2. Changeset  ID in Git is long 40-digits hex-hash, hardly readed by human
3. Git haven't natively support for RCS-style keyword expansion.
4. If you still want it, read this [full answer on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/enable-ident-string-for-git-repos/1796675#1796675) from @jakub-narebski. [Pro Git reading](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) can help understand also (with nice example of using filters for $Date$ keyword constructing)