# How do I find the version of file by git file hash

Tags: git

I have a script that generates other scripts.  I want to put some identity in the generated script so that I can find the version of the script that generated it.

I have followed the instructions on [How do I enable ident string for Git repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792913/35577) (which uses $Id$).  Now that I have hash for the file (not the commit), how do I go find the version of the file from the repo?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git cat-file`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cat-file.html).

To see the *type* of an object, use `git cat-file -t revspec`, where *`revspec`* is any valid revision specifier (see [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)).  For instance:

```
$ git cat-file -t master
commit
```

To see the *contents* of an object, use `git cat-file -p revspec`.  If the *`revspec`* identifies a "blob" (a file), this gives you the raw contents of the file.  Note that no filters are applied.

(If it identifies a commit, tag, or tree, you get a printable representation of that.)

(You can only apply filters to paths, not raw object-IDs.  Turning a blob ID into a set of paths that specify that blob is nontrivial, but not impossible unless the blob is unreferenced; however, there may be multiple paths referring to a single blob, a la Unix/Linux hard links.)