# Ignore .gitattributes while doing a checkout

Tags: git, jgit, gitattributes

JGit does not support [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). There is a [5 year old bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342372) on that topic.

As a consequence, the [`ident`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/how-do-i-enable-ident-string-for-git-repos) macro isn't used by JGit (`$Id` expansion).

If you checkout a branch with regular console `git`, which supports `.gitattributes` and `ident`, the macro expansion happens. If you then do `git blame`, it doesn't see a difference in lines with the `$Id$` macro. Which is expected.

If you then do `jgit blame` on that same repo, you get `Not Committed Yet` on lines that contain the `$Id$` macro.

I found this out while [investigating an issue with Sonarqube's Git plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/05ybdlF51UI). The friendly people there opened a [bug](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARSCGIT-12) to followup.

My question: **how do I tell regular `git` to ignore `.gitattributes` while doing a checkout?**
Extra brownie points: I need to do this in Jenkins, so preferably out of the box with some twiddling of the Jenkins Git plugin.

*To be honest: I don't have high hopes for a positive answer. The best thing would be that JGit gets their act together and supports `.gitattributes`. But this is not the place for that rant.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take benefit from JGit own bug and use it to do the checkout in Jenkins (in fact I was convinced Jenking Git plugin was already using JGit).

Comment: I cannot verify that right now. Due to a Groovy bug in Jenkins 2.6, I am unable to access the configuration page of the job that does the git checkout.