# How to automatically pull the version number?

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php, command-line-interface

I'm writing a [Symfony Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) PHP application which [takes a version number in the constructor](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.html).

```
$app = new Application('myapp', '1.0');
```

I've already found that it's easy to forget to bump the version number when making a new git tag release. How can I do this dynamically/automatically?

Aside from here on SO, I [searched packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=git%20tag%20version) pretty deeply because I thought for sure this was a common thing, but wasn't able to turn up anything.

I thought at first to write a function that would do something like this:

```
chdir(__DIR__);
shell_exec('git describe --abbrev=0 --tags');
```

But because I [globally require this CLI app with composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global), it doesn't have the git repository with the source code.

My next idea is that I know I can at least get it from composer

```
composer global show myname/mypackage
```

But this spits out a ton of information and there's no option that I'm aware of to just show the version number. I feel like filtering through all this with something like regex might be overkill. Is there any better way?

Comment: What's the objective? To detect the latest version (by tag) of the repository in the current working directory that the app is running in?

Comment: Yes, that would be good, but like I mentioned in my question, there's no git repository when installed via composer.

Comment: The objective is when I tag a new release, I don't want to have to remember to first update that hard coded string with the version number.

Comment: Right. Can you retrieve it dynamically every time from an API, or it that overkill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling the version number from somewhere could be difficult, because you could run an older version of the application but wrongly pull the newest version number.

You could add a "release.version" file to your repo that only contains the version number and read this to pass it to the constructor.

Then you can use a git hook like pre-commit to update this file before you commit a tag.

This however is not recommended in distributed systems because it could lead to collisons, but for smaller teams or teams with a dedicated release manager it might be ok.
Read here: https://wincent.com/blog/automatic-deployment-numbering-in-git
and [How do I enable ident string for Git repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/how-do-i-enable-ident-string-for-git-repos)

It would maybe be enough to have a pre-commit hook that checks for a new tag and just reminds you to increment the version in the code ;).