# How to get git commit SHA inside BUILD.bazel?

Tags: bazel

My goal is to create a zip file that has a git commit SHA of the current HEAD in its name using Bazel.
I know there is a technique called Stamping, but I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around how I can use that for what I need.
I already have some code (rule) that creates the zip file that I need:

```py
def go_binary_zip(name):
    go_binary(
        name = "{}_bin".format(name),
        embed = [":go_default_library"],
        goarch = "amd64",
        goos = "linux",
        visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    )
    # How do I add the git commit SHA here?
    native.genrule(
        name = "{}_bin_archive".format(name),
        srcs = [":{}_bin".format(name)],
        outs = ["{}_bin.zip".format(name)],
        cmd = "$(location @bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper/zipper) c $@ {}=$<".format(name),
        tools = ["@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper/zipper"],
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting the git commit SHA inside your macro or rule implementation isn't possible within bazel. Output paths are intended to be deterministic. You *can* get that information inside of a file that is available in a rule (see option 2 below.)

If your goal is to create a zip with the git commit SHA in the filename you you have a couple options.

1. Write a script that runs outside of bazel to copy the zip from bazel into your workspace.

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   bazel build //:example
   cp $(bazel info bazel-bin)/example.zip example-$(git rev-parse HEAD).zip
   ```
2. Create a rule that uses stamping to generate a script file that you can run via `bazel run` to copy the archive for you. Inside your rule implementation you can access the `stable-status.txt` and `volatile-status.txt` files (documented at this link: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#workspace-status) with `ctx.info_file` and `ctx.version_file` respectively.

   Do note that `ctx.info_file` and `ctx.version_file` are undocumented so it is unclear whether or not this API is stable or will be supported in the future ([see github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/9363).)

Comment: I'm going to try number 2, if I can figure it out based on the instructions I'll mark this as the correct answer. As it stands I'm still fairly confused to be honest.

Comment: If you don't mind a C++ dependency I wrote a utility library for this exact use case + more here: https://github.com/zaucy/bzlws/blob/master/docs/index.md (`bzlws_copy`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a git feature, which replace any occurence of `$Id$` in files specified in a `.gitattributes` file https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792913/4638604.