# Can ClearCase's findmerge tool ignore a predefined conflict?

Tags: clearcase

There are 2 branches of a file. I have to merge from one branch to the other. The automatic merges fails as there are conflicts. The conflicts are due to the date command output stored in file. Can the findmerge tool ignore some conflicts using some filter options? I want findmerge to ignore `Date: .*` lines and auto merge the rest of file.

As there are many such files, manual merge of all such file having difference of "Date: .*"  takes too much time. How can I automate such a merge ?

Date is different in all 3 files, so there is conflict:

```
file1.txt@@/main/branch1/LATEST
Date: 03/03/2010 11:00PM
Some  information1

file1.txt@@/main/branch2/LATEST
Date: 11/11/2009 10:30AM
Some  information1
New   information2
New   information3

Base file: file1.txt@@/main/main/20
Date: 07/07/2005 05:30AM
Some  information1
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword expansions in ClearCase [have been debated before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645424#645424): without the right type manager, it isn't supported.
(Not mentioning the fact is [doesn't bring much value in a VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127177/to-put-the-prefix-revision-number-to-codes-by-git-svn/1127241#1127241))

The crux of the issue is that the findmerge algorithm has a case where the actual file content is compared. Unfortunately, **findmerge does not use the type manager's compare function, but something hard coded** and will think the files are different even though the only difference is in the keywords

You still have in theory a way to [develop a type manager, combined with a trigger, as discussed here](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/cgi-bin/cmwiki/view/CM/BasicClearCase#1.2.5). This isn't trivial by any mean, so the best solution is to:

- either avoid modification in *both* branches (the merge will then be trivial for that section)
- or avoid keyword expansion entirely (for instance, a meta data like a date should be associated with the revision date itself, and not as a textual metadata within the data itself)