# github repos cloning, but no tags/branches recreated?

Tags: git, github

I've been cloning a few repos from github that, even though I know they have branches/tags, do not have them once I clone them onto my local drive. strange. 
I try to list the tags (git tag) but nothing comes up...
I would look into .git/refs/tags/ and that too is empty.

the repos in question are:
http://github.com/jchris/hovercraft.git
http://github.com/apache/couchdb.git

any ideas? I really need specific tags/branches, and not the HEAD of the master

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in [GitHub remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/):

> Running `git clone URL` will automatically create a new subfolder, fetch the contents of the repo into this subfolder, then create and checkout the default branch (usually “master”).
>   If there are other branches on the remote you will need to create a local branch to work in, for example `git checkout -b fix_stuff origin/fix_stuff`

Meaning all the branches should be there, but in the '`remotes`' namespace of your repo.
But you usually have only *one* [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch) created for you after a clone (the default one, usually '`master`').

Try a `git branch -a` or a `gitk --all` to check if you do see them.

---

As for tags (normally present in [`refs/tags` namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tag-and-a-branch-in-git)), [let's hope it is not a repeat of this issue](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2771-tags-not-showing-up) (March 2010).

> Sorry everyone, we had a little snafu with the tag parser... tags should be showing up again as caches clear.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've cloned the repository, only master is set up for you. You can start using a remote branch locally with the command:

```
git checkout -t origin/1.2.x
```

That creates a local branch named `1.2.x` that "tracks" (e.g., pushes and pulls from) the remote branch, and switches you to it.

As previously mentioned, you can see all branches (local & remote) with:

```
git branch -a
```

Tags should be a part of the cloned repo automatically. You can see all tags with one of these:

```
git tag     # Show bare list of tags.
git tag -n  # Show tags with first line of annotation specified at tag creation.
git tag -n4 # Show tags with 4 lines of annotation, if available.
```

Hope that helps!