# git: starting anew on existing repo. Branch or tag for legacy version?

Tags: git, branch

This is a minor issue but I'd like to check people's thoughts.

I have been contracted for a project, they have an existing repo which is outdated. They want to use that repo though to have the new version. This new version will be completely built from scratch.

Is it better to create a tag on master on the current repo for the "legacy" code, or to create a branch for it and have a "clean" new master?

I don't see much difference at first sight really. Maybe it is more efficient to have separate branches as the old code history doesn't get replicated, but that's just a guess of mine.

Comment: I got some ideas from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tag-and-a-branch-in-git, and I settled for creating a branch. The decision is based on the idea that with a branch, theoretically someone could continue working on the legacy version (although very unlikely...) totally independently :)