# Are tags independent entities?

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

I'm trying to figure out where exactly is a tag stored.

Online docs tell me to simply `git tag -a <version> -m <message>` but what should I do after that? Does tagging create a specific point in history, like a commit? Or is the tag stored in the staging area until I commit it? Or does the tag add itself to the last commit? I'm having trouble finding an answer.

Comment: Tagging is like a putting a (very) sticky note on a commit, so you can refer to the latter easily. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/how-is-a-tag-different-from-a-branch-which-should-i-use-here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag is just a label that points at a commit (it's similar to a branch name in this sense, although a tag points at a fixed commit rather than auto-advancing).  It isn't part of a commit.  After creating a tag, there really isn't anything to do "after that".  You can now use that tag to reference that particular commit, so you can do things like see all the changes since that tag:

```
git diff mytag
```

Or you can create a new branch based on that tag:

```
git checkout -b newbranch mytag
```

As to your first question ("where exactly is a tag stored?"), the answer is either (a) in the `.git/refs/tags` directory, or (b) in the [.git/packed-refs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) file.

Comment: Note that annotated tags create tag objects in gits object database (.git/objects) in addition to the ref.  Light-weight tags on the other hand only create a ref.

Comment: Right.  For annotated tags, the value of the ref will point to the tag object, while for lightweight tags the refs points directly to a commit.