# Github Branch,Tag: How to get a specific release of a code?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-tag

I'm new to Git hub and I got confused about the concept of tag and branch(explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/how-is-a-tag-different-from-a-branch-which-should-i-use-here))
I would like to get an stable version of PhantomJS(version 2.1.0) from git hub. But I don't understand if I should do:

```
git checkout master
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
git fetch upstream
git rebase --onto tags/2.1.0 upstream/master master
```

or

```
git init
git remote add -t 2.1 -f origin https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
git checkout 2.1
```

Would you please explain me which one and why?

Answer (score 9):

You should just clone the repository and then checkout the tag:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
$ cd phantomjs
$ git checkout 2.1
```

Keep in mind that being on a tag, you cannot commit any local change you would make. For that, you must be on a branch. What can be confusing is that the command is `git checkout` for both branches and tags.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I will try to answer on it:

Git stores data about all changes that made in code (this include data about branches and tags)
When you clone a repository you will get complete history for that repository

So, `git clone https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git` will clone project
If you have forked project you can do
`git clone https://github.com/<YOUR_USERNAME>/phantomjs.git`

Now change directory to phantomjs: `cd phantomjs/`

To see history you can execute `git log` or `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` for prettier view

To list all tags on repository execute
`git tag`

Finally, to create branch with tag 2.1.0 execute
`git checkout 2.1.0 -b v2.1.0`
After this you will have two branches `master` and `v2.1.0`

I hope this helps