# Add submodule with specific tag not branch in one command

Tags: git, git-submodules

For a rails template I'd like to add a submodule of a specific tag to new rails apps. To keep this simple I'd like to avoid going into subdirectories and running git commands there.

`git submodule add --branch v1.3.37 git@example.com:foo.git vendor/foo`

Is what I would like to use, but it does not accept tags for the `--branch` parameter:

`fatal: 'origin/v1.3.37' is not a commit and a branch 'v1.3.37 cannot be created from it Unable to checkout submodule 'vendor/foo'`

Is there a simple way to add a git submodule on a specific tag?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is possible.

This is the submodule [command line reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

```
git submodule [--quiet] add [<options>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--depth <depth>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
```

As you can see, right now it only supports branch option, and in terms of Git objects, the difference between branch and tag is discussed in here [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/how-is-a-tag-different-from-a-branch-which-should-i-use-here):

> branch
>
> > A "branch" is an active line of development. The most recent commit on
> >     a branch is referred to as the tip of that branch.
>
> tag
>
> > A ref pointing to a tag or commit object. In contrast to a head, a tag
> >     is not changed by a commit.

So, until Git team supports SHA commit checkout for submodule, you cannot checkout specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workaround: just `fork` target repository and create a new branch from upstream tag.

```sh
git clone git@my.example.com:foo.git /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo
git checkout -b release-v1 v1
git push --set-upstream origin release-v1
cd ~/workspace && git submodule add --branch release-v1 git@my.example.com:foo.git vendor/foo
```

But later you will have to create new branches from news tags before using it as git submodule.