# Merge a branch with tag - Gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitlab, git-merge

In our enterprise, as part of DevOps team, we do not have privilege to install `git` on local laptop and fetch the GitLab code repo. Jenkins tool has ssh access to GitLab repo, but we do not have ssh access to jenkins(Git installed). We have access to see the repo through a GitLab portal, something like [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master) and then configure Jenkins to fetch code from GitLab.

So, I cannot run commands like `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` on my laptop, to understand the merge aspect.

---

Under [tags](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tags) section of Gitlab portal in our enterprise, I see an entry, as shown below:

[image]

---

I understand that tag is an alias of `git commit` hash key(40 char), **but I need** clarification on above entry where tag name(`sprint12-tag`) is specified for a merge of branch(`feature-branch-x`) to branch(`develop`).

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457136/3317808),  *A tag represents **a version of a particular branch** at a moment in time. A branch represents a separate thread of development that may run concurrently with other development efforts on the same code base.*

So, my understanding is that, a tag `sprint12-tag` has been assigned to a specific commit(could not be a latest commit) on `feature-branch-x`, as shown below:

[image]

---

As of now, I see below options in GitLab home page, when I click on left-top icon

[image]

---

**Questions:**

0) How to view such graphs(above) on GitLab portal? unless we run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` on local laptop...

1)
With the above tag(`sprint12-tag`) on any branch(in this case `feature-branch-x`), Can I say that, developer has run below commands?

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge sprint12-tag # ignoring the latest commit c5 on 'feature-branch-x'

$ #   or it can be `git merge e324567`
```

2)
How do I understand below entry?
 as shown [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tags) for example...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On GitLab, select `Repository > Graph` in the left sidebar to view the repo's commit tree. This will show all of the commits and merges, annotated with branch names and tags.

`[2.2]` in the image below is a tag.

I would say that, generally, developers tag commits manually *after* merging some work. You do your final merge or PR from `dev` into `master` and get a resulting merge commit. This merge commit is then tagged as `release2.0` and never moves from that commit. I'm sure this is automated in some organizations as well.

> How do I understand the below entry?

That image shows a tag named `v11.7.5`. This tag has been annotated *on GitLab* (not in git itself) as "Version v11.7.5". The commit the tag points to is `c5b5b18b`. That commit's commit message is `Update VERSION to 11.7.5`

example:

https://code.sealedabstract.com/drewcrawford/CaveJohnson2/network/master

[image]

Comment: Query updated with the option which is different from what you see

Comment: I do not see `Repository` option after `Projects`

Answer (score 1):

> A tag represents a version of a particular branch at a moment in time.

This quote is misleading. Tags and branches are two independent things. You should think of a tag as a static marker at a particular commit. On the other hand, a branch is dynamic and moves as you add commits to the branch. For more discussion about the different between branches and tags, check out [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) on our [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sister site.