# Can anybody diagram the concept of SVN Branching?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have read [Branching / Tagging](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) twice now.  I cannot seem to grasp this idea.  I want to have a a good understanding of branching, to prevent errors to the main line.

Since I am a visual learner, can anybody diagram the concept of SVN Branching?  Or is it possible in plain English to describes the concepts?

lets say i have 3 developers on a team and one repo "out_app"
how would dev1 create a branch and merge back to the main line?
how would this effect dev 2 and 3?

detail the steps, menue items clicked, settings entered... for the above questions.

Answer (score 11):

See [A Visual Guide to Version Control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/).  Great article.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can start reading the [SVN readbook on Branching and merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge)

[image]

It is based on cheap copies:

> Subversion's repository has a special design.
>   When you copy a directory, you don't need to worry about the repository growing huge—Subversion doesn't actually duplicate any data. Instead, it creates a new directory entry that points to an existing tree. If you're a Unix user, this is the same concept as a hard-link.
>   As further changes are made to files and directories beneath the copied directory, Subversion continues to employ this hard-link concept where it can. It only duplicates data when it is necessary to disambiguate different versions of objects.

Answer (score 1):

(In my opinion) the best modelling and explanation of good revision control branching is in [The Flow of Change by Laura Wingerd](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/conferences/us/2005/presentations/Wingerd.pdf), a conference presentation made about Perforce. It describes the **tofu scale**, where changes flow from "soft" branches (untested, unstable) up to "hard" branches (released, well-tested) as revisions become more solid.

It provides a very understandable metaphor for managing revisions and branches; I cannot recommend highly enough that *everyone* reads through this presentation and absorbs its ideas.

[tofu scale http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/136976/tofu%20scale.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/136976/tofu%20scale.png)

Comment: +1. I mentioned her (Laura Wingerd) in my answer on the SO question "When should you branch?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch/2107672#2107672