# .NET Rails-style Database Migrations with Feature Branching

Tags: .net, git, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have looked at all of the options on [.NET Migrations Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313/net-migrations-engine), and found the engines that use Rails-style migrations to be the most interesting, primarily because they are written in a database-agnostic way that can be easily used against a different database platform.

However, I saw one glaring problem that none of them seem to solve out of the box: source control branching.

The Scenario

1. Feature 1 is being developed on branch1 and adds a column to a table named column1
2. Feature 2 is being developed on branch2 and adds a column to the same table named column2
3. Release 1.1 is made that includes feature 2, but feature 1 is not complete yet
4. Feature 1 is completed and merged to trunk
5. Release 1.2 is made, however the new column1 field that went into the trunk was at version 1 (tied to release 1.1 directly in the code), so does not get updated in the database when it is migrated

With tools such as [Migrator.NET](https://github.com/migratordotnet/Migrator.NET), the problem seems to be that the migrations version is related to the actual software release, not the SCC commit. However, the attribute must be added to the code in source control. I have seen examples where a date was used instead of a version, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue at hand any more than incremental versioning.

The closest to an answer I found was on the [Liquibase FAQ page](http://www.liquibase.org/faq), however the solution would require code changes in the case of the Rails-style frameworks in .NET (even in [Rik Migrations](http://www.rikware.com/page/RikMigrations---Upgrading.aspx), which structures the attributes similar to the liquibase changelog files):

> **Does Liquibase work with branches?**   Yes. Since each change is independent, database changes that had been made in a different
>   branch, then merged in will be run the next time Liquibase is run. You
>   may run into a problem with the order that the statements are ran, but
>   any issues you have can be easily solved by re-ordering the changelog
>   files.

What is the typical way to handle this issue?

In case it makes any difference, I am using Git for source control. Note I already saw the post entitled [Database migrations in a complex branching system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409204/database-migrations-in-a-complex-branching-system), but it didn't really provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this some thought, and this is what I have come up with so far. I haven't decided on a migration framework yet, but the below method assumes something like [Migrator.NET](https://github.com/migratordotnet/Migrator.NET) that uses attributes. However, this could be adapted to other migrators as well.

Since the problem lies in the fact that the migrations are versioned prematurely (during development instead of during release), my first instinct is to come up with a workflow that ensures that the migrations cannot be versioned until the release. This can be accomplished with the build script, unit tests, and source control. Here are the steps:

1. Create a unit test that fails when MigrationAttributes exist with a version higher than the current database version that is run during the CI process
2. Create a unit test that fails when changes are made to any migrations equal or lower to the current database version that is run during the CI process
3. Add a step prior to CI build that locates all of the classes that inherit from the Migration class and add a MigrationAttribute with a version 1 higher than the current database version. This ensures the migrations will run successfully in the CI process. Ensure the unit test in steps 1 and 2 are run prior to this step.
4. Add a step after the CI build to set the current database version in the database table back to the currently released database version. Our CI process database versioning is only temporary.
5. Add a step prior to the release build that locates all of the classes that inherit from the Migration class and add a MigrationAttribute with a version 1 higher than the current database version. Commit this code change back into the trunk.

The common premise here is that all of this can be fully automated, and database migration version attributes are added as both a temporary CI build step and a release step (by the build process, not manually). The unit tests ensure that no cheating can be done with regard to editing the migrations or versioning them too early in the development cycle.

Of course, steps 3 and 4 could be replaced with a drop/recreate methodology in the CI process and it would probably be more reliable. The key is that the database versioning happens and is checked into source control during the release (and never before).

**Versioning**

To accommodate this workflow, I am considering making the database version part of the AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2.3.4+<GitHash>-<DBVersion>")]
```

So in the above example, the version of the database will be inserted after the Assembly. This will allow me to use the regular major/minor + build versions, but also tracking the database release version (and the head commit in Git) for the current build right in the assembly. The release process could then increment this version accordingly and all unit tests and other steps would follow. Note that AssemblyInvormationalVersion shows up as Product Version in Windows.

The GitHash is only the first 7 characters, which is generally enough to make it unique anyway.

**Summary**

The main thing to take away from this is that the branching can be as complex as it needs to be without intefering with the database release because the source code will not contain database versioning attributes in any branch (if they do, the build will fail). The branches will, however, contain the information necessary to migrate the database, which really is a development step, not a release step.

Clearly, the unit tests and build scripts will require reflection, code injection, as well as working with the source control provider to ensure the rules are followed, but it is all surely possible.

I have not tested this in practice, but if I can't find another solution, this is probably the direction I will go.