# Generate change scripts from SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change database development from creating change scripts to automatically generating change scripts from the declarative defitinitions. How would I go about doing that for PL/SQL on an Oracle DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a short introduction at [section "Version Datamodel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977688/database-version-change-control-for-data-not-schema/21023781) here on stackoverflow. I've worked on this interesting area for many years, starting in 1994 on Oracle7 to allow automatic overnight going in production. Not all nights I got my sleep...

For Invantive Producer, we have a boot-package that runs on Oracle 11 and up and takes care of automatic upgrades, but it is over 8.000 lines. The boot package is called by PL/SQL when bootstrapping and later on takes it instructions from a repository with software definitions. The repository is described at [Technical Reference Manual](http://www.invantive.com/any/doc/2012r1%20itgen%20b52%20technical%20reference%20manual%20abbridged.pdf), also a [Diagram](http://www.invantive.com/any/doc/2012r1%20itgen%20b52%20er%20diagram.pdf) is available and might give some inspiration.

I can give you a sample of such as procedure, please let me know what types of objects you would like to automatically generate DDL for, then I can add things when necessary.

```
procedure verify_index
( p_table_name   varchar2
, p_index_name   varchar2
, p_index_unique boolean default null
, p_column_list  varchar2
)
;
```

and

```
procedure verify_index
( p_mode         pls_integer
, p_table_name   varchar2
, p_index_name   varchar2
, p_index_unique boolean default null
, p_column_list  varchar2
)
is
begin
  verify_index
  ( get_table_name(p_mode, p_table_name)
  , get_index_name(p_mode, p_index_name)
  , case
    when p_mode = g_history_mode
    then false
    else p_index_unique
    end
  , p_column_list
    || case
       when p_mode = g_history_mode
       then ',h_date_starts,h_date_ends'
       else ''
       end
  )
  ;
end;

--
-- Verify existence of an index with the indicated column list.
--
procedure verify_index
( p_table_name   varchar2
, p_index_name   varchar2
, p_index_unique boolean default null
, p_column_list  varchar2
)
is
  l_index_exists_anywhere boolean;
  l_index_exists_on_table boolean;
  l_create_index          boolean;
  l_ist_column_list       varchar2(4000);
  l_soll_column_list      varchar2(4000);
  l_story                 varchar2(4000);
  l_stmt                  varchar2(4000);
begin
  l_story := 'Reason: ';
  --
  -- Determine whether to recreate the index.
  -- In the process, drop the current index when not correct.
  --
  l_index_exists_anywhere := index_exists(p_index_name, null, null);
  l_index_exists_on_table := index_exists(p_index_name, null, p_table_name);
  if l_index_exists_on_table
  then
    l_ist_column_list := index_column_list(p_index_name, true);
    l_soll_column_list := lower(p_column_list);
    if identical_character_sequence(l_ist_column_list, l_soll_column_list)
    then
      -- Column lists are equal. Just check uniqueness.
      if index_exists(p_index_name, p_index_unique, p_table_name)
      then
        null; -- Do nothing.
        l_create_index := false;
        l_story := l_story || ' index ' || p_index_name || ' already exists on the correct table with the correct column list ' || l_soll_column_list || '. Do nothing.';
      else
        drop_index_existing(p_index_name);
        l_create_index := true;
        l_story := l_story || ' index ' || p_index_name || ' has the correct column list ' || l_soll_column_list || ' but on a different table. Recreate index.';
      end if;
    else
      drop_index_existing(p_index_name);
      l_create_index := true;
      l_story := l_story || ' index ' || p_index_name || ' has the incorrect column list ' || l_ist_column_list || ' but should have ' || l_soll_column_list || '. Recreate index.';
    end if;
  elsif l_index_exists_anywhere
  then
    drop_index_existing(p_index_name);
    l_create_index := true;
    l_story := l_story || ' index ' || p_index_name || ' exists on the wrong table. Recreate index.';
  else
    l_ist_column_list := null;
    l_create_index := true;
    l_story := l_story || ' index ' || p_index_name || ' does not yet exist. Create index.';
  end if;
  --
  -- Now l_create_index describes whether to create the index or not.
  --
  if l_create_index
  then
    /* Only uncomment this when itgen_log is available. During bootstrapping it is not possible
       to use itgen_log. */
    -- itgen_log.debug('Create index ' || p_index_name || '. ' || l_story);
    l_stmt := 'create'
              || case
                 when p_index_unique
                 then ' unique'
                 else ''
                 end
              || ' index '
              || p_index_name
              || ' on '
              || p_table_name
              || '('
              || p_column_list
              || ')'
              ;
    execute_dynamic_sql(l_stmt);
  end if;
end
;
```