# Addressing migrations and schema changes when working with git branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have a doubt about create a new branch.
For example I already created a branch for `category-has-many-through`( i created `categorizations` and category model).
And I have everything nice and working.
But during I was developing that branch I was thinking in another way for do the things completely different. For another case.
So I change for master and create another branch `category-has-many`. And I want to do this new idea, for future implementation or in case the needs for this.
So I notice that my schema has the another tables that I created before.

I thinking to create a new migration and commit or delete the tables of the has-many-through way....
I know for the things run as expected I'll need to do a `rake db:drop` and then a setup.
But this is my experienced thoughts. And I want to know if I'm doing the things right or I need to do these in another better way?
Anyone have this experience? If yes, and if you want to share the better way of do this cases I will appreciate.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6409204/7976758