# Manage different database versions or change database according to the git branch version with backward compatibility

Tags: git, liquibase

Currently our company use liquibase to manage database changers and git for versioning control.
Also we have several testing environment for QA.
let say we have feature branch f1 and f2.
when we remove table or column in f1 branch and we test it. 
with the same db we have to f2 branch which is there are no any db change with it. 
Now f2 branch will get error in run-time saying there are no such a column or table.

what is best way to manage db version with git branch? Is there any plugin to manage this scenario ?

we can get original database dump and put them with branch changes, but it is time consuming and inefficient method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database migrations in a complex branching system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409204/database-migrations-in-a-complex-branching-system)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+database+branches