# Git Workflow: Clarification and Avoiding Antipatterns

Tags: git

I am in the process of developing a Git workflow for a web app project I am working on. I have used Git for several years, but only as a solo developer. I have put a set of procedures together, and yesterday ran across this article on HN: http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html

Based on the article I have adjusted my procedures and would appreciate some feedback. I want to make sure I am interpreting the article correctly and not contributing to issues down the road. **Based on the article in question, and the desire to provide good working standards, are there any issues with the following procedures?**

---

### Basics

- **master branch** - The main, working branch into which all code
  development is merged. This represents the most recent additions to
  the codebase from individual development branches.
- **'dev_' branches** - Local, private development branches should be used for developing new
  features. If you need to push the branch to the server (so you can
  switch easily between computers) please make sure that the dev branch
  name includes the user name, like 'dev_andy_authentication'.
- **staging branch** - Before deployment of certain code from the master branch,
  the code must be tested in an environment that matches the production
  environment as closely as possible. Code from the master branch is
  merged into the staging branch, tested, and, once it passes tests, is
  eligible for production.
- **production branch** - Stable code from the staging branch is integrated into the production branch, tagged with a release version number, then deployed to the production server(s).

---

### Development

Branch: master

- Use local, private feature branches to separate code:

  - Switch to ‘master’ branch: git checkout master
  - Create a new, private feature branch: git checkout -b dev_newfeaturename
  - Make feature additions.
  - Stage changes: git add .
  - Commit changes in ‘dev_newfeaturename’: git commit -m “commit description”
- To integrate changes from 'dev_newfeaturename' branch:

  - Switch to ‘master’ branch: git checkout master
  - Check for remote changes to ‘master’: git pull --rebase origin master
  - If changes in 'dev_newfeaturename' branch are relatively small:

    - Integrate changes from ‘dev_newfeaturename’ branch into master: git merge --squash dev_newfeaturename
    - Write a detailed commit message of changes implemented from 'dev_newfeaturename' branch: git commit -v
  - If changes in 'dev_newfeaturename' branch are more complex, requiring multiple commits to remain in the history:

    - Switch to ‘dev_newfeaturename’ branch: git checkout dev_newfeaturename
    - Reintegrate any changed ‘master’ code into ‘dev_newfeaturename’ branch: git rebase --interactive master
    - To cleanup history by combining commits, change the operation from "pick" to "squash", which squashes the second commit into the first
    - Switch to ‘master’ branch: git checkout master
    - Push changes to remote ‘master’: git push origin master
  - Check for remote changes to ‘master’: git pull --rebase origin master
  - Push all changes to 'master' back to the server: git push origin master
- ‘Master’ becomes the working tree of all currently developed features.
- Periodically pull ‘master’ changes from remote: git pull --rebase origin master

---

### Staging

Branch: staging

- Once a release of a certain number of features/bug fixes has been scheduled, ensure that ‘master’ is functioning properly then merge into ‘staging’ by:

  - Switch to ‘staging’ branch: git checkout staging
  - Integrate changes from ‘master’ into ‘staging’: git merge --no-ff master
  - Push ‘staging’ to remote repo: git push origin staging
- Deploy ‘staging’ branch to staging server and test rigorously - staging server should replicate production environment as closely as possible.
- If any testing fails, return to ‘master’ branch, fix any associated issues, and restart the Staging process.
- If all testing passes, proceed to Production process.

---

### Production

Branch: production

- Once code in the staging branch has been tested and has passed, switch to the ‘production’ branch: git checkout production
- Integrate changes from ‘staging’ into production: git merge --no-ff staging
- Tag code with sequential release version number: git tag -a 0.1
- Push ‘production’ to remote repo: git push origin production
- Deploy ‘production’ branch to production server and test to ensure proper deployment.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific:

Based on the article in question, and the desire to provide good working standards, are there any issues with the listed procedures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

> If changes in '`dev_newfeaturename`' branch are more complex, requiring multiple commits to remain in the history:
>
> - Switch to ‘`dev_newfeaturename`’ branch: `git checkout dev_newfeaturename`
> - Reintegrate any changed ‘`master`’ code into ‘`dev_newfeaturename`’ branch: `git rebase --interactive master`
> - To cleanup history by combining commits, change the operation from "pick" to "squash", which squashes the second commit into the first
> - Switch to ‘`master`’ branch: `git checkout master`
> - Push changes to remote ‘`master`’: `git push origin master`

I think you forget the fast-forward merge of '`dev_newfeaturename`' into ‘`master`’:
The rebase allows you to replay '`dev_newfeaturename`' on top of ‘`master`’, cleaning up the commits in that process. That is good.
But if you want to push back master to the remote, master needs those cleaned commits in its history: `git merge dev_newfeaturename

---

Regarding a branch per development state (staging, prod), I wouldn't recommend that approach, unless you are actively producing new commits in those branches.
Remember the sentence about no-ff in the article you reference:

> The only remaining argument for `–no-ff` is “documentation.”
>   People may use merge commits to represent the last deployed version of production code.
>   **That’s an antipattern. Use tags**.

Comment: Thanks so much for catching the lack of merging back into master - I will add a merge step after the switch to master and before the push to the remote. With regard to not using `-–no-ff` or feature branches, would you recommend just keeping master as the public integration branch, and using tags to mark release points? Is there any case where it would be beneficial to have a staging or production branch?

Comment: @theandym: I have always been wary of such "branches" with a DVCS. You can have staging or production *repositories* (i.e. environments where you push to), but the tags and labels (and don't forget `git notes` to add any status you want on those commits) should be enough to record those states ("staging" or "prod"). Branches that makes senses are for maintaining a prod (branch 1.1 for all fixes made for 1.1 for instance). More generally: as soon as you perform some *development* in parallel of some other development, a branch make sense. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107672 .

Comment: That makes sense. Having development state (staging, prod.) branches always seemed a little contrived and arbitrary, but I could never figure out why. Your explanation and answer to the other question really helps define a best practice for DVCS branching. Thank you again!