# Adding Local repository Github Desktop whole User file

Tags: git, github, repository, github-desktop

I'm trying to add a local repository using the github desktop app. But when I'm linking the folder, it keeps trying to add my User folder, thus making it well over the bytes limit and I'm not able to add anything because I keep getting this error:
"The output from the command could not fit into the allocated stdout buffer. Set options.maxBuffer to a larger value than 10485760 bytes"

I'm checked the repository settings and my primary remote repository is "(fetch)". Adding a new repository and then copy/pasting the code into that new repo works fine but I want to know why adding my existing local repo won't work.

Comment: Dragging and dropping the project doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I actually found the answer to my problem. I was using the Github Desktop Beta version. I'm still not sure why the problem happened in the first place, but to fix this I just made sure to download the non-beta version at https://desktop.github.com/ at the bottom of the webpage rather than the one at the top.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old issue: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/969

Solution:

- Uninstall current GitHub desktop's version.
- Then, update your GitHub Desktop version.

Comment: I was on the latest Github Desktop version. But I did so anyways and the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and unistalling and than updating GitHub didn't work.

This was the solution for me:

- Open git bash
- Create your Git repo `cd c:\path\to\yout\project && git init . && git add` ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081060/creating-a-new-git-repo-from-existing-files-on-windows))
- Than 'Add axisting repository' on GitHub desktop should work