# Version Control concepts and best practices

Tags: version-control

I have worked with Source Control softwares like VSS, TFS, ClearCase, SVN, etc. but my work has primarily been centered around the typical source control operations like get latest, add new files, etc. I want to have a more in-depth understanding of the basic source control concepts like versioning strategies, concepts of a trunk and branch, merge and fork operations, tags and history views. These should be agnostic to the package that is being used and should discuss about the general concepts and best practices. Can anyone point out a good book or internet resource to learn about these concepts.

Comment: [This blog series](http://www.kevingao.net/sourcesafe-vss-how-to) covers how a typical centralized version control system works.

Comment: link broken [correct link](https://www.codepool.biz/sourcesafe-vss-how-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn this links,

1. http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html
2. http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/

they may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

A good introduction regarding branches and merge workflow:

The chapter 7 of Practical Perforce (Laura WINGERD - O'Reilly) is a good introduction (VCS agnostic) to merge workflow between different kind of branches: " "**[How Software Evolves](http://oreilly.com/catalog/practicalperforce/chapter/ch07.pdf)**" (pdf).
I also detail those strategies in "[When should you branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107672/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

The [**VS Branching and Merging Guide**](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) by the ALM Rangers is an excellent resource. It is TFS centric but contains major SCM concepts.