# Should multiple modified source files be added to Git at once, even if the changes made between them are independent?

Tags: git, github

I'm teaching myself Github and have trouble understanding the overall way it is to be used. I'm not sure if my work flow is correct. My understanding a project corresponds to a repo, so I have one for sorting algorithms. I had implemented a quicksort algorithm. Yesterday I began implementing an introsort, but I made a minnor change to a comment in the quicksort.

I then did the following

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "Began creating introsort implementation"
3. git push origin master

However, since a minor chagne was made to the quicksort source, now in Github quicksort has the message "Began creating introsort implementation" which kind of isn't the right place for it.

Is this a problem? What did I do wrong? I guess I shouldn't have used `git add .` and instead did the `introsort` source by itself. Someone was telling me that a new branch should be made while working on different parts of the same project. Is this right e.g. a new branch for each module? And then they can be merged together when they're working? So using Git branches out at first and then unbranches?

Comment: This question is a bit subjective, but common practice is that each commit should correspond to a discrete, logical, and complete change, but it takes some experience to develop a sense of what that means, and it will vary from team to team or project to project.

Comment: @DietrichEpp when should a new branch be made? In the context of a solo developer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks I googled but that didn't come up

Comment: I just googled "when should I branch" to find that question.

Answer (score 1):

You make a new branch before you start work on a new functionality. You commit your work to that branch. Once your new functionality works, you make a pull request so others can review changes and merge it into the target branch.

Your workflow is correct, if you work solo, but, if not, you should add `git pull` just before pushing.

Comment: When starting a new project, which do you do first: create the local project using the IDE, or create the repo first (and initialize it with the README file) and clone it?

Comment: I usually create the repo and then just clone it locally - this is simplest. 
If you have some files already, just go ahead and make a new local repo by `git init`, then do `git remote add` for remote repo.  If you already have project from IDE, I advise you to make .gitignore file, to ignore IDE specific project files and compiled files. Note that git will not allow you to commit an empty folder.

Comment: Thanks. So how exactly do you do the first scenario, with an IDE like Netbeans? For example you create a repo on Github, then clone it. But obviously there's no source code yet as you just made it. So what option do you choose in the IDE, I would think use source code from existing project but there isn't any yet? In the past I've tried just making new source code but this causes a merge conflict.

Comment: Well I dont really understand what are you trying to achieve. Also, I have never used any IDE for managing my git repos, but it must be possible. I usually just use git from command line. You can only get merge conflicts when there are changes in one and the same file on two branches, that are being merged.