# which one is better for source code control on github ? branch or subfolder?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

My friend asked me a question:

> When we develop a same Android app on github, we have 2 ways to develop in parallel:
>
> 1. The first way is forking a new branch repository and follow the
>    request&merge process.
> 2. The second way is create a new folder in the same repository in the
>    same repository.

For the second way, my friend said that it will be easier for his job as he can always pull all codes and merge by himself.

According to my experiences, I didn't do it and I always use branch and merge.

Why one method would be superior to the other?

I can provide a sample GitHub project with sub-folder and the project is [AndroidTVLauncher](https://github.com/JackyAndroid/AndroidTVLauncher).

For other projects on GitHub, as I know, they most follow the first way and use branch and merge.

Comment: what you mean with `(2)The second way is create a new folder in the same repositor in the same repository.`

Comment: dear @Koop4, I mean that I can create a new folder under the original project folder. I didn't do this before and this way is suggested by my friend.

Comment: so what does he put into that subdirectory? does he copy the project with his modifications? does he take original project as a template for some another project?

Comment: @max630, my friend said using sub-folder will be eaiser for his merge and code comparsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a branch is always preferable to a new folder within the same repo: that is how a modern version control isolate new development efforts with code isolation: see "[When should you branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107672/6309)".

But don't forget that with recent versions of Git, you can clone a repo once, but checkout *twice*, in different folders, each one on their own branch ([`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)).
So you can have both: a dedicated folder, for a dedicated branch.

Comment: got it and thank you and I will share this with my friend.