# revision vs. version

Tags: version-control, configuration, release, cmmi

I am kicking off some process improvements at a new company.  One of the areas to concentrate on first is CM.  I was asked during a briefing of what I am doing what is the difference between revision and version.  I gave my explanation and then followed up with an email of the following link:  http://www.product-lifecycle-management.com/plm-revision-version.htm

What I would really like to know is do most places use revision or version as the main identifier and why the preference to one or the other?  I have my preferences, but would like an opinion from the community.

Comment: a bit related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056912/source-control-vs-revision-control/1056947#1056947

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my experience, revision is more of an internal term that matches up with the unique identifier of a check-in or build. Version is a label of a released product so that you know whether the version is newer or not than what you have.

Comment: Exactly. in giving a full version info bit we may say "SVN Revision 386, Version 1.2.1"

Comment: @Earlz Exactly. In other words, a version is a _named revision_.

Answer (score 3):

In my view,
versions are used when the configuration item features are different or more than the previous one. While revisions is the number of times that you find error and fix in the same version i.e., functionalities remains same but the errors are fixed.

Comment: Short and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can have a software in a version i.e. Adobe PS 6. But the software can be released under that version with several revisions. Where a revesion is created on any change on the soruce code. So if you want to make changes to the PS 6 version, you will make commits and create revisions on the way, but the version stays the same.

Usually version is split into major and minor verosion, hence small changes will change the minor version number and bigger changes will lead to a major change.