# Document Version Control

Tags: version-control

I create documents on a regular basis for my freelance projects and keep updating it on an ongoing basis. Till now I was able to manage the documents using the Google Docs, and was manually updating the revision history.

However, the volume of documents which are getting edited is increasing. And now I want to employ an open source (or something free) software to manage the version control of the documents. It would be nice if all this can be done on cloud.

Please suggest me the solution to the above problem I am going through.

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs itself seems already adapted to your need, since it [supports revision history](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190843).

[image]

A Version Control solution would be needed only if you wanted branches and merging between those branches (as mentioned in "[Source control vs. Revision Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056912/source-control-vs-revision-control/1056947#1056947)").

Answer (score 1):

The [Revisionator](http://revisionator.com) is like google docs, but it has full blown version control built in. The problem with Google Docs is that there is no concept of a working version. Stuff is added to revision history as soon as anyone types anything, even if it doesn't conceptually represent a new version. Also, since everyone is editing the document at the same time, different people's changes are mixed up with each other. Gives you a nasty mess.

Since the revisionator uses working versions, you can stage your edits, resulting in a much more understandable revision history.

It also supports diffing, branching, and merging.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is a mobile document management solution called SavvyDox.  It controls versions through a cloud based server and provides an attractive alternative to Word Track Changes while still using Word - and we all know that everyone would love an alternative to Track Changes.

The version control capabilities ensure that you always have a current copy of the document on your desktop, highlighted by a green check indicating that it is current.  You can easily compare the current version to previous versions and if necessary, you can even pull up previous versions.

Reviewers are allowed to add suggested changes to the document, but the only person who can actually change the document is the author - and authors love that.

Check it out at http://www.savvydox.com/project-management/ and sign up for a no charge trial.

If you're interested in seeing OVUM's SWOT analysis of SavvyDox, try this link http://www.savvydox.com/SavvyDoxSWOT.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try MagnetSVN for Microsoft Office. This tool integrates Subversion into MS Office.
It is not a free however but has 30-day trial. In case you want to try it for more time - no problem, send request for longer evaluation from http://magnetsvn.com