# Is it possible to view multiple git branches at the same time for the same project?

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I have 2 branches, which are not ready to be merged yet, but have some complementary logic, which I'd like to review (before merging)

Can I check out multiple git branches of the same project? Is it possible?

Comment: You will be able to do so with Git 2.5+ and its new `git checkout --to=<path>` command. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30186481/6309).

Comment: The actual syntax is `git worktree add <path>`. I have updated [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30186481/6309).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can simply copy the repository to a new location (either by literally copying the directory, or using [`git clone --shared`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---shared)) and check out one branch per location.

You can also use [`git-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for creating multiple working directories from a single instance of a repository.

Otherwise, the primary means for comparing files between branches prior to merging them is `git diff`.

Answer (score 21):

With Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015), a Git repo will support **multiple working trees** with **`git worktree add <path>`** (and that will replace `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir`)

Those "linked" working trees are actually recorded in the main repo new `$GIT_DIR/worktrees` folder (so that work on any OS, including Windows).

See more at "[**Multiple working directories with Git?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)"

Comment: Note that unlike git-new-workdir, git worktree does not allow you to create multiple worktrees for the same branch :/

Comment: @NikiC You can by adding the `--force` flag (`-f` also works) according to [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_options)

Comment: Just a little meta info here: only one of the worktrees has a `.git` _directory_ that contains all the objects (blobs, commits, trees). All other worktrees have a `.git` _file_ that contains something like: `gitdir: /path/to/project/.git/worktrees/main` (main is a name I gave to my worktree) i.e. it points back to your base worktree

Comment: @Honey True. And I have [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599305/6309) how `git worktree` proposes a set of commands to manage those worktrees (`move`, `prune`, `list`, ...) –

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with appropriate care. However you are taking one of the copies 'away' from the regular git directory using `--work-tree=<path>` option, so changes there won't be seen by git unless you specially tell it. I gave an example here [single-working-branch-with-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331715/single-working-branch-with-git/7347935#7347935) - see the UPDATED segment.

Note that the `git-new-workdir` doesn't work on Windows XP as it requires Unix style links.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind it to checkout each branch on separate project.
So:
1. checkout branch A on primary clone (1)
2. create a new clone (2)
3. checkout branch B in clone 2

Second approach could be to create a new branch (aka C) and merge both branch A and B to it.
If they are complimentary than this might help with your review.

Comment: I have tried doing this but when I check out the branch in one repo in my intellij other intellij having clone also gets impacted .any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

Now `git` includes the command `worktree` to do exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned, you can diff branches with git diff:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>…]

This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the tip of a different branch.
```

Excerpt above is from Git documentation.