# Git worktree: two worktrees point in the same location, cannot be prune

Tags: git, git-worktree

When I do `git worktree list`, it display follows.

```
/path/to/workspace  c943d35 [master]
/path/to/workspace  ef4df56 (detached HEAD)
```

It is my working directory (not worktree directory). I do not know how it happened, and how to clean it. I've try `git worktree prune`, but it does not change anything. Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: what is in the /path/to/workspace/.git file?

Comment: @max630 there is `branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  index  info  logs  objects  ORIG_HEAD  packed-refs  refs  svn  worktrees`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`git worktree` -- details](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_details) mentions:

> Each linked working tree has a private sub-directory in the repository’s `$GIT_DIR/worktrees` directory.

Check the content of your `main repo/.git/worktrees` and see if there is a sub-folder that you could manually remove.

---

Git 2.20 (Q4 2018) fixes a bug in which the same path could be registered under multiple worktree entries if the path was missing (for instance, was removed manually).
Also, as a convenience, expand the number of cases in which `--force` is applicable.

See [commit 684e742](https://github.com/git/git/commit/684e742249b48ec0c5491a98fa3b1427793738ce) (30 Aug 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 3a54043](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a5404333c6c8b5897e78c9dcb711d623035791b), [commit f414310](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4143101cbb26d189f63f2d29875f4acc07b2730), [commit 68a6b3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68a6b3a1bd45eb1814a0c1cedfe347692c3f2ff7), [commit e19831c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e19831c94f91fd410fe001c0372b9c88b40d335b), [commit cb56f55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb56f55c16c128e18449c9417dc045f787c1b663), [commit 45059e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45059e6468ab5710748c8827d5bf1f4c7c69d6d1), [commit 602aaed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/602aaed03f7f82323d88703d6fa2263a13c37907), [commit e5353be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5353bef550d91655b3f8fb443a26c0ba209153f), [commit 4c5fa9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c5fa9e6c4091eea9d8df3466b18ddb2812cd934) (28 Aug 2018) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1c515bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c515bf7e2b395509a122fb92cd6f925bf09a6fe), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `worktree`: delete `.git/worktrees` if empty after '`remove`'

> For cleanliness, "`git worktree prune`" deletes the `.git/worktrees` directory if it is empty after pruning is complete.
>
> For consistency, make "`git worktree remove <path>`" likewise delete `.git/worktrees` if it is empty after the removal.

---

The same Git 2.20, when traversing objects for reachability and deciding what
objects are unreferenced and expendable, have been taught to also
consider per-worktree refs of other worktrees as starting points to
prevent data loss.

See [commit 14f74d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14f74d59072c7bf0586b15165538373bed898f18) (03 Nov 2018), [commit c9ef0d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9ef0d95ebf3ca154ef1d8345e9713eddecd9c90), [commit b29759d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b29759d89a688bf6d198786757111d690a08cbdf), [commit ab3e1f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab3e1f78ae8ecb3371cf85a36d73fd341fad3884), [commit 061e420](https://github.com/git/git/commit/061e420a4d3a87ea331eb51f2b92b6b97f3115da), [commit 3a3b9d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a3b9d8cde4ed647b1c56a8097f6db8e269bbc71) (21 Oct 2018), and [commit 8aff1a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8aff1a9ca5a266020fe5b1bd8c54228581e34530), [commit 5c79f74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c79f74f0514a29fe182b0a442406105fb6f1660) (29 Sep 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
See [commit a8c754d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8c754d4e2ced5439c23e8cf4636c24749ea1ddc) (21 Oct 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e146cc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e146cc97be4c054c60d38e9f4edcdc33205bf563), 13 Nov 2018)</sup>

In particular ([commit 3a3b9d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a3b9d8cde4ed647b1c56a8097f6db8e269bbc71)):

> ### `refs`: new ref types to make per-worktree refs visible to all worktrees

> One of the problems with multiple worktree is **accessing per-worktree refs of one worktree from another worktree**.
> This was sort of solved by multiple ref store, where the code can open the ref store of another worktree and has access to the ref space of that worktree.
>
> The problem with this is reporting.
> **"`HEAD`" in another ref space is also called "HEAD" like in the current ref space.**
> In order to differentiate them, all the code must somehow carry the ref store
> around and print something like "`HEAD from this ref store`".
>
> **Instead of entering a separate ref space, we make refs from other worktrees available in the current ref space**.
> So "`HEAD`" is always HEAD of the current worktree, but then we can have
> "`worktrees/blah/HEAD`" to denote HEAD from a worktree named
> "`blah`".
> This syntax coincidentally matches the underlying directory structure which makes implementation a bit easier.
>
> The main worktree has to be treated specially because well... it's
> special from the beginning.
> So HEAD from the main worktree is acccessible via the name "`main-worktree/HEAD`" instead of "`worktrees/main/HEAD`" because "`main`" could be just another secondary worktree.
>
> This patch also makes it possible to specify refs from one worktree in
> another one, e.g.
>
> ```
> git log worktrees/foo/HEAD
> ```

---

That (the new refs "`worktrees/<name>/HEAD`") leads to Git 2.23 (Q2 2019), where the code now sanitizes the names given to worktrees, to make sure these refs are well-formed.

See [commit 1de16ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1de16aecf51daf5794aa074f6dd133e088a12690) (08 Mar 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0d107b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d107b19890db191c9281bff67180389fb53df24), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `worktree add`: sanitize worktree names

> Worktree names are based on `$(basename $GIT_WORK_TREE)`.
> They aren't significant until [3a3b9d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a3b9d8cde4ed647b1c56a8097f6db8e269bbc71) (`refs`: new ref types to make per-worktree refs visible to all worktrees - 2018-10-21, Git v2.20.0-rc0), where worktree name could be part of a refname and must follow refname rules.
>
> [Update '`worktree add`' code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1de16aecf51daf5794aa074f6dd133e088a12690/builtin/worktree.c#L293-L300) to [remove special characters to follow
> these rules](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1de16aecf51daf5794aa074f6dd133e088a12690/refs.c#L60-L80). In the future the user will be able to specify the
> worktree name by themselves if they're not happy with this dumb
> character substitution.

---

And the same Git 2.22.1 (Q3 2019) mentions "`git worktree add`" used to fail when another worktree connected to the same repository was corrupt, which has been corrected.

See [commit 105df73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/105df73e71a9eb901d7ca96f12ce3645729ae486) (13 May 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 933f294](https://github.com/git/git/commit/933f294877bac77c6159d93220c5910954712025), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `worktree add`: be tolerant of corrupt worktrees

> `find_worktree()` can die() unexpectedly because it uses `real_path()`
> instead of the gentler version.
>
> When it's used in 'git worktree add' (added in [cb56f55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb56f55c16c128e18449c9417dc045f787c1b663) (`worktree`: disallow adding same path multiple times, 2018-08-28, Git  v2.20.0-rc0), or since v2.20.0. Though the real bug in `find_worktree()` is much older) and there's a bad worktree, this `die()` could prevent people from adding new worktrees.
>
> The "bad" condition to trigger this is when a parent of the worktree's
> location is deleted. Then `real_path()` will complain.
>
> Use the other version so that bad worktrees won't affect '`worktree add`'.
> The bad ones will eventually be pruned, we just have to tolerate them for a bit.

---

Before Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), in rare cases "[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) `add <path>`" could think that `<path>` was already a registered worktree even when it wasn't, and refuse to add the new worktree.
This has been corrected.

See [commit bb69b3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb69b3b009c0093417942dba136b81fbf614c4ed), [commit bb4995f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb4995fc3fab35b56f1ca48cda9187bcf340e643), [commit a80c4c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a80c4c22147bae6d9f9b907b81ab3f4d129ab690) (24 Feb 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 49e5043](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49e5043b09fffb0411e8bae19d60014e72a36fd0), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb69b3b009c0093417942dba136b81fbf614c4ed): don't allow "`add`" validation to be fooled by suffix matching
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Cameron Gunnin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> "[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) `add <path>`" performs various checks before approving `<path>` as a valid location for the new worktree.
>
> Aside from ensuring that `<path>` does not already exist, one of the questions it asks is whether `<path>` is already a registered worktree.
> To perform this check, it queries `find_worktree()` and disallows the "`add`" operation if `find_worktree()` finds a match for `<path>`.
> As a convenience, however, `find_worktree()` casts an overly wide net to allow users to identify worktrees by shorthand in order to keep typing to a minimum.
> For instance, it performs suffix matching which, given subtrees "`foo/bar`" and "`foo/baz`", can correctly select the latter when asked only for "`baz`".
>
> "`add`" validation knows the exact path it is interrogating, so this sort of heuristic-based matching is, at best, questionable for this use-case and, at worst, may may accidentally interpret `<path>` as matching an existing worktree and incorrectly report it as already registered even when it isn't.
> (In fact, `validate_worktree_add()` already contains a special case to avoid accidentally matching against the main worktree, precisely due to this problem.)
>
> Avoid the problem of potential accidental matching against an existing worktree by instead taking advantage of `find_worktree_by_path()` which matches paths deterministically, without applying any sort of magic shorthand matching performed by `find_worktree()`.

And:

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a80c4c22147bae6d9f9b907b81ab3f4d129ab690): improve `find_worktree()` documentation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> Do a better job of explaining that `find_worktree()`'s main purpose is to locate a worktree based upon input from a user which may be some sort of shorthand for identifying a worktree rather than an actual path.
>
> For instance, one shorthand a user can use to identify a worktree is by unique path suffix (i.e. given worktrees at paths "`foo/bar`" and "`foo/baz`", the latter can be identified simply as "`baz`").
> The actual heuristics `find_worktree()` uses to select a worktree may be expanded in the future (for instance, one day it may allow worktree selection by `<id>` of the `.git/worktrees/<id>/` administrative directory), thus the documentation does not provide a precise description of how matching is performed, instead leaving it open-ended to allow for future enhancement.
>
> While at it, drop mention of the non-NULL requirement of `prefix` since `NULL` has long been allowed.
>
> For instance, `prefix_filename()` has explicitly allowed `NULL` since [116fb64e43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/116fb64e439d3744d0f244a51d7a6d714b7703ae) (`prefix_filename`: drop length parameter, 2017-03-20, Git v2.13.0-rc0), and `find_worktree()` itself since [e4da43b1f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4da43b1f063d227b5f7d2922d27458748763a2d) `(prefix_filename`: return newly allocated string, 2017-03-20, Git v2.13.0-rc0).

---

Note that the same worktree directory must be registered only once, but "[`git worktree move`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" allowed this invariant to be violated, which has been corrected with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020).

See [commit 810382e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/810382ed378731314c03627a8a2d8962b814ad17), [commit d179af6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d179af679bd5f70506732e1c9242d367efc7ea42), [commit 916133e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916133ef8edcda54b0bff03a949c0858cd8d3280), [commit 4a3ce47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a3ce479ce7c8f268f42b725e471e35967da9b4f), [commit dd9609a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd9609a12e83969be6536853b2846866dafdfc98), [commit 1b14d40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b14d40b385580a366c92f8c2a9373e6fd7cb26f) (10 Jun 2020), and [commit c9b77f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9b77f2cea2f0b4ee34d1d7a25cd1ebed767caf4) (08 Jun 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9740ef8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9740ef888edadcb12442faf2a690016bb8a2c03c), 22 Jun 2020)</sup>

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), The same worktree directory must be registered only once, but "[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) move" allowed this invariant to be violated, which has been corrected.

See [commit 810382e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/810382ed378731314c03627a8a2d8962b814ad17), [commit d179af6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d179af679bd5f70506732e1c9242d367efc7ea42), [commit 916133e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916133ef8edcda54b0bff03a949c0858cd8d3280), [commit 4a3ce47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a3ce479ce7c8f268f42b725e471e35967da9b4f), [commit dd9609a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd9609a12e83969be6536853b2846866dafdfc98), [commit 1b14d40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b14d40b385580a366c92f8c2a9373e6fd7cb26f) (10 Jun 2020), and [commit c9b77f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9b77f2cea2f0b4ee34d1d7a25cd1ebed767caf4) (08 Jun 2020) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9740ef8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9740ef888edadcb12442faf2a690016bb8a2c03c), 22 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a3ce479ce7c8f268f42b725e471e35967da9b4f): prune duplicate entries referencing same worktree path
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> A fundamental restriction of linked working trees is that there must only ever be a single worktree associated with a particular path, thus "[`git worktree add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" explicitly disallows creation of a new worktree at the same location as an existing registered worktree.
>
> Nevertheless, users can still "shoot themselves in the foot" by mucking with administrative files in `.git/worktree/<id>/`.
>
> Worse, "[`git worktree move`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" is careless and allows a worktree to be moved atop a registered but missing worktree (which can happen, for instance, if the worktree is on removable media).
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> $ git clone foo.git
> $ cd foo
> $ git worktree add ../bar
> $ git worktree add ../baz
> $ rm -rf ../bar
> $ git worktree move ../baz ../bar
> $ git worktree list
> .../foo beefd00f [master]
> .../bar beefd00f [bar]
> .../bar beefd00f [baz]
> ```
>
> Help users recover from this form of corruption by teaching "[`git worktree prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" to detect when multiple worktrees are associated with the same path.

And:

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/916133ef8edcda54b0bff03a949c0858cd8d3280): prune linked worktree referencing main worktree path
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jonathan Müller</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> "[`git worktree prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" detects when multiple entries are associated with the same path and prunes the duplicates.
>
> However, it does not detect when a linked worktree points at the path of the main worktree.
> Although "[`git worktree add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" disallows creating a new worktree with the same path as the main worktree, such a case can arise outside the control of Git even without the user mucking with `.git/worktree/<id>/` administrative files.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> $ git clone foo.git
> $ git -C foo worktree add ../bar
> $ rm -rf bar
> $ mv foo bar
> $ git -C bar worktree list
> .../bar deadfeeb [master]
> .../bar deadfeeb [bar]
> ```
>
> Help the user recover from such corruption by extending "[`git worktree  prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)" to also detect when a linked worktree is associated with the path of the main worktree.

---

Note that Git 2.30 does list locked worktrees:

See [commit c57b336](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c57b3367bed488469d24a21446731e9e71846ded):

> ### worktree: teach `list` to annotate locked worktree

> The "`git worktree list`" shows the absolute path to the working tree,
> the commit that is checked out and the name of the branch. It is not
> immediately obvious which of the worktrees, if any, are locked.
>
> "git worktree remove" refuses to remove a locked worktree with an error message. If "`git worktree list`" told which worktrees are locked in its output, the user would not even attempt to remove such a worktree, or would realize that
> "`git worktree remove -f -f <path>`" is required.
>
> Teach "`git worktree list`" to append "`locked`" to its output.
> The output from the command becomes like so:
>
> ```
> $ git worktree list
> /path/to/main             abc123 [master]
> /path/to/worktree         456def (detached HEAD)
> /path/to/locked-worktree  123abc (detached HEAD) locked
> ```

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), "[`git worktree add --lock`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/01369fdfd3d0deec41c55306dae42f00dfbfa582/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L213)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt---lock))</sup> learned to record why the worktree is locked with a custom message.

See [commit 0db4961](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0db4961c49bb70cef89ed3d7c90f8f5d9dfc822d) (15 Jul 2021), and [commit f7c35ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7c35ea2a1292d581ca79d395fc978f92a3aec5b), [commit f9365c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9365c0a24b9d2346a9b2b5a24e1fa02039f23e5) (11 Jul 2021) by [Stephen Manz (`SRManz`)](https://github.com/SRManz).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 01369fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01369fdfd3d0deec41c55306dae42f00dfbfa582), 28 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`worktree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0db4961c49bb70cef89ed3d7c90f8f5d9dfc822d): teach `add` to accept `--reason <string>` with `--lock`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Stephen Manz</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> The default reason stored in the lock file, "`added with --lock`", is unlikely to be what the user would have given in a separate [`git worktree lock`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0db4961c49bb70cef89ed3d7c90f8f5d9dfc822d/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L104)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#Documentation/git-worktree.txt-lock))</sup> command.
> Allowing `--reason` to be specified along with `--lock` when adding a working tree gives the user control over the reason for locking without needing a second command.

`git worktree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0db4961c49bb70cef89ed3d7c90f8f5d9dfc822d/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L12):

> ```
> git worktree add [-f] [--detach] [--checkout] [--lock [--reason <string>]] [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<commit-ish>]
> ```

`git worktree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0db4961c49bb70cef89ed3d7c90f8f5d9dfc822d/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L245):

> With `lock` or with `add --lock`, an explanation *why* the working tree is locked.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem. I am hoping there is an "automatic" way of doing it.

Comment: @cityzz In your case, there is no automatic "prune" as this should not happen (two entries with the same path). A manual "cleanup" remains the quickest fix.