# How to run two MATLAB instances simultaneously with different pathdef's?

Tags: git, path, git-clone, matlab

I'm developing my own brain imaging toolbox that runs under MATLAB & SPM8, and at the same time I have a `git clone`'d version of my own toolbox code directory (local git repository) for running analyses, this setup is created according to Kevin Reid's answer on [How to work simultaneously on several different versions of files with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665752/how-to-work-simultaneously-on-several-different-versions-of-files-with-git), which solved a part of the problem (how to have different versions of same `.m` file accessible at the same time, and still synchronizable by using `git fetch` or `git pull`).

However, my MATLAB install is in neither of these git directories; it's installed normally in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/`. MATLAB looks for functions according to `pathdef.m`, which is stored in `which pathdef` (`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m`) as a regular function. So I cannot have two MATLAB instances running simultaneously so that they had different `pathdef`'s, at least not by modifying `pathdef.m` file.

Of course MATLAB has to know beforehand where to look for `pathdef.m` to define the path. Is there a way to change `pathdef.m` lookup path eg. by some MATLAB command line argument or from MATLAB console? Or by some other means, so that I could have two MATLAB instances running simultaneously with different `pathdef`'s? Or should I install MATLAB in two different directories? I'm interested in all kinds of solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me offer an alternative approach. It involves creating [shortcuts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-shortcuts-to-rerun-commands.html) inside the MATLAB IDE.

Simply create two shortcuts, each include something like:

```
addpath(genpath('/path/to/project_branch'))   %// add branch (and subfolders) to MATLAB path
cd('/path/to/project_branch')                 %// navigate to directory
```

*(Explanation: The call to [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) will not save the changes system-wide, but will only persist for the current session, unless you call [`savepath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html))*

Now whenever you start a new MATLAB session, and you decide to work on one or the other branch, simply click the corresponding shortcut and start hacking away...

Better yet, if you consider one branch as *stable* and the other as *dev*, you can add the stable one to the path permanently, and selectively add the development version on the top of the path `addpath('...','-begin')` using a shortcut, thus shadowing the other branch for the current session only.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Gunther's answer is also useful, but this one permits changing the path on the fly easily, without restarting a new MATLAB instance. Both solutions have their benefits.

Comment: I would also recommend using `addpath` and `cd`, however if you have multiple paths to work with, you might want to create a simple `changepath('projectbranch')` function instead of a button per branch to keep the amount of shortcuts limited.

Answer (score 3):

yes, there is. Set the environment variable MATLABPATH before starting matlab (from a terminal)

```
export MATLABPATH=/yourdir
```

Comment: Does this leave you with this setting for all future matlab sessions (unless you manually clean up)?

Comment: The environment variable `MATLABPATH` exists only as long as the session in which it's started is alive. Of course you can add this command to your `.bashrc` or `.profile` file, so it's started upon every new session. It might also be possible to set the `MATLABPATH` in `matlabrc.m`, don't know for sure. If your looking for just changing that, I'd look into that