# Change matlab path on startup (On a PC platform)

Tags: matlab, svn, path

I'm working on 2 branches in SVN and I'd like to have 2 shortcuts (or 2 .bat files) to start matlab with path correctly defined upon the branch I'm currently working with. For instance:

```
[Matlab-trunk.bat] ==> Would look for some pathdef-trunk.m
~matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\apps
~matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\audiovideo
~code\trunk\MyToolboxes\Common
~code\trunk\MyToolboxes\Miscellaneous
~code\trunk\MyToolboxes\etc\etc ...

[Matlab-BranchLala.bat]  ==> Would look for some pathdef-lala.m
~matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\apps
~matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\audiovideo
~code\branchlala\MyToolboxes\Common
~code\branchlala\MyToolboxes\Miscellaneous
~code\branchlala\MyToolboxes\etc\etc ...
```

I have read this thread:

[How to run two MATLAB instances simultaneously with different pathdef's?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10903487/684399)

And I like [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10903546/684399) where I would simply have to define for `MATLABPATH` environment variable before to start Matlab ... but it seems this only works for Unix\Mac platforms ... maybe I should mimic similar idea by manually editing the `matlabrc.m` file ... or maybe you have a better idea ?

**EDIT**

Humm ... maybe I should dynamically switch `startup.m` file before to start and add a `matlabpath(...)` in there ... but I don't know where it is stored, the command `userpath` is returning `` on my PC.

NB1: I'm working with Matlab R2013b on a PC platform

NB2: I cannot move to `git` do in-place branch-switching for now on (this was one solution I though about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [different startup folders](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/changing-the-startup-folder.html) for each of the shortcuts.
Then, at each different startup folder define `pathdef.m` file with the different paths.

Comment: This works great and it's easy to set up. Thanks a lot!