# Getting OpenCV2.4.2 with GIT for Windows

Tags: git, opencv, tags, git-checkout

I want to get the **OpenCV2.4.2** source files for windows in order to generate the libraries myself. I run the command

```
git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git
```

This actually gets the 2.4.9 repository which I don't want. There is a GIT option

`git reset  --hard <commit code>`

that is supposed to get back to the desired commit. The thing is that I found that there are way too many commits and I don't know which one is the version 2.4.2!

- **How can I download version 2.4.2 from GIT?**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1655666/1225337

Comment: very interesting. But still there is the problem on how to know which id corresponds to version 2.4.2

Comment: @Jav_Rock try to issue `git tag` to get tag name of version, then issue `git checkout tagname`

Comment: Great news to hear OpenCV migrated from SVN to git! Every time when a branch was created in SVN, it took me almost one day to run `git svn fetch` and slowed down my PC! With git, this will no longer be a problem of slow fetch.

Comment: @linquize If opencv has migrated to **Git**, then we all should migrate to **Git**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look for the tags using:

```
git tag
```

Look for OpenCV 2.4.2, or whatever you want, and then checkout with your election:

```
git checkout 2.4.2
```

in your case.

---

If you want to pull the latest 2.4 branch, then you can do:

```
git clone -b 2.4 --single-branch https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git Opencv-2.4
```