# using git-svn in place of (Tortoise) Subversion - limitations or surprises?

Tags: windows, git, svn, version-control

I have been using `git` for source control, but now I'm taking over a project where the source control was done with [Tortoise Subversion](https://tortoisesvn.net/). I haven't used [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) before, but it appears that it was written to give users a Git-like interface to Subversion repositories. Are there any limitations or gotchas to be aware of when using [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) instead of (Tortoise) Subversion? For example, might checking in work with [git-svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) result in surprising side effects?

Comment: Your question is a little broad. What exactly are you worried about?

Comment: @Confiqure e.g. (1) is there anything in Subversion that git-svn might not be able to do? (2) If files are checked out from a Subversion repository using git-svn, then checked with changes, will there be any changes to the Subversion metadata that a new user might not expect?

Comment: [Here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/images-git/7/78/Git-svn-cheatsheet.pdf) is a neat little cheat sheet that shows what kinds of svn commands that map to git-svn commands. Would be useful to give to your developers. I'm in a similar situation as you.

Comment: @Confiqure thanks. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11506143/266457) also looks useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of git over git-svn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286297/what-are-the-advantages-of-git-over-git-svn)