# How is dvcs (git/mercurial) branching and merging support better than svn's?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Lots of articles on dvcs systems claim superior branching and merging support as one reason to move from svn to dvcs systems. How exactly do these systems do branching and merging differently that makes it better?

Comment: I've often wondered this same thing. In every article I've read (mostly about Git), it's just stated as plain fact with no supporting evidence or examples.

Comment: @nickf: how all the related SO questions in the right section of this page don't answer your question? This has been answered many times on SO.

Comment: @VonC, suprisingly, this is the first question I've seen on it. Looking at the "related" column on the right here, I do see your point though.

Comment: @nickf: I mean, I was already stating this has been answered over and over and over again in this SO question in 2010 (March): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518779/what-are-the-benefits-of-mercurial-or-git-over-svn-for-branching-merging (see the comments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is branching and merging easier in Mercurial than in Subversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995/why-is-branching-and-merging-easier-in-mercurial-than-in-subversion)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically, the difference between merge-tracking in git and svn was this: git has merge-tracking, and until version 1.5, svn didn't. At all. If you wanted to make a merge you had to always specify exactly what changes were to be merged, and if you merged one branch into another more than once, you would have to manually keep track of which revisions had and hadn't been merged, and manually select only the changes that hadn't been merged yet, to avoid conflicts. Good luck with that if you ever cherry-picked any changes.

Beginning with version 1.5 (released in 2008), if your client, server, and repository are all up-to-date, then svn is capable of acting a lot more intelligently; it uses properties to keep track of where a branch came from and what changes have already been merged into it. The upshot is that in many cases you can just `svn merge BRANCHNAME` and have the right thing happen. But due to its "bolted on" nature it's still not very fast and [not entirely robust](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2897). Git, on the other hand, *has* to handle merge scenarios well because of its DVCS nature, and it was designed from the beginning with data structures (like the particular kind of DAG it uses) and algorithms (such as recursive-merge and octopus-merge) that are suited to the task.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is not, contrary to popular perception, due to the distributed nature of DVCS's, vs Subversion's centralised model. There is nothing inherent in a centralised model that entails that branching and merging will be substandard.

My take is that Subversion made a massive design gaffe by deciding to model code-base directory structure, branching and tagging (and all manner of other code management patterns) in a single, unified directory tree, which made the problem of reliably detecting branching activity one hundred times more difficult than it would have been if branching were explicit in the model.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the human components of any version control system.  Earlier today I created and deleted 3 different local git branches, because that was the least disruptive way to accomplish cleaning up a problem on the main branch.  Try that on centralized version control and you are likely to get a lecture from the server admin or a storm of angry emails, if you even have privileges to do it at all.  The very fact that you can have branches in a private repo removes many cultural barriers to using branches effectively.  The algorithms used by centralized systems are catching up to DVCS.  Those human factors will remain.

Answer (score 3):

From [Joel's hginit](http://hginit.com/00.html):

> Here’s the difference. Imagine that
>   you and I are working on some code,
>   and we branch that code, and we each
>   go off into our separate workspaces
>   and make lots and lots of changes to
>   that code separately, so they have
>   diverged quite a bit.
>
> When we have to merge, Subversion
>   tries to look at both revisions—my
>   modified code, and your modified
>   code—and it tries to guess how to
>   smash them together in one big unholy
>   mess. It usually fails, producing
>   pages and pages of “merge conflicts”
>   that aren’t really conflicts, simply
>   places where Subversion failed to
>   figure out what we did.
>
> By contrast, while we were working
>   separately in Mercurial, Mercurial was
>   busy keeping a series of changesets.
>   And so, when we want to merge our code
>   together, Mercurial actually has a
>   whole lot more information: it knows
>   what each of us changed and can
>   reapply those changes, rather than
>   just looking at the final product and
>   trying to guess how to put it
>   together.

Comment: From my understanding, svn builds on cvs.  CVS stores the current version intact, and reverse diffs to older versions.  When you go to merge in svn (or CVS), it looks at the current file content prima facie from the two that you're merging and tries to smash them together.  git/mercurial, otoh, keep a recipe of how each version came into existence, so the tool has more information to make sound decisions.  I think the difference is that git/mercurial go out of their way to make sure that merging is easy (from a tool perspective), whereas svn just doesn't.

Comment: Even if git has more information about what each developer did, wouldn't it still create the same conflicts when two developers change the same code?  Say we have a variable and two developers separately refactor that variable and change its name to something different. It has to still be a merge conflict, right?

Comment: @Samuel yes, but not all conflicts are fundamental like the one you mention. Some of them are *spurious*, and could be avoided by a better merge algorithm.

Comment: @hobbs, I don 't disagree in theory, but I also can't remember ever getting a conflict in SVN that could have been resolved automatically.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because, as @nmichaels rightly points out, I had it backwards.

Comment: I've done some testing, and found that, no svn doesn't store versions, it stores deltas (two commits to a 250 kB file with a small edit produces a 95 kB rev (≈gzip) followed by a 1/2 kB rev), as does hg (a single 92 kB data file). Git, on the other hand, stores full versions of everything (two 100 kB blob files). So, while my original view was off the mark, it wasn't entirely backwards, and Joel's post still makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Branching or tagging in SVN is merely copying a particular directory and its subdirs to another location within the same repository. In git, branches (and tags) are instead described as metadata (much like CVS), except that it does not throw all this data in a single file, but many (allowing for much faster updates since you don't have to rewrite a huge "foo.c,v" for example). Furthermore, git makes heavy use of pointers. (http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/ ) so there is in fact, few to update in the first place when something changes (e.g. a commit is made).

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the repository format used by most DVCS's - the Directed Acylic Graph.

SVN Will just store your history in a series of lines, each branch its own line. But a DVCS will store it in a DAG that contains much better information for merging.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @Samual Neff Unfortunately its hard without ASCII art and I'm not exactly good at ASCII art.

Comment: @Samuel, there's a pretty good description [here](http://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html).