# Do three-way merges exist in Subversion?

Tags: git, svn, merge

I know there's the sync merge which copies over the next set of changes from trunk. According to the [docs](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/site/publish/docs/svn-merge.txt), this is how the sync merge works:

> Subversion will locate all the changes on 'trunk' that have not yet
> been merged into the 'feature' branch. In this case that is a single
> range, r100:200. In the diagram above, L marks the left side (trunk@100)
> and R marks the right side (trunk@200) of the merge source. The
> difference between L and R will be applied to the target working copy
> path.

It keeps track of what has and hasn't been merged into the feature branch using the mergeinfo.
There's also the reintegrate merge which is described as:

> The feature branch was last synced with trunk up to revision X. So the
> difference between trunk@X and feature@HEAD contains the complete set
> of changes that implement the feature, and no other changes. These
> changes are applied to trunk.

Both of these sound like two-way merges, which seems a lot less robust than a three-way merge like in git.

Edit:
So, it looks like SVN *does* do 3-way merges, but the descriptions of sync and reintegrate merges above (and those found from [some other sites](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SVN/SymmetricMerge#SymmetricMerge-Backgroundon3-waymerging)) still sound like 2-way merges.  If, and how, is this different from what git does with its merge?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472251/14044430) suggests that 3-way merges are pretty much the same across multiple VCS, and that it's how merges are tracked that makes the difference.  So does that mean that SVN only chooses its base tree differently than git does?

Comment: SVN is older than Git and has a lot of quirks, but it does support proper 3-way merging. To make this work right, SVN needs what they call *merge metadata*. In very-old SVN, and some special cases, there's no merge metadata available and you have to supply it. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html for gory details.

Comment: Whichever way a three-way merge is done internally, what I'm missing from SVN is the git-like support in the merge tool in case of conflicts. In git, you have _our_, _base_ and _target_ plus the merged output view. Subversions is one short (I believe the _base_ is missing).

Answer (score 1):

In short, SVN does appear to have three-way merge functionality. See file `subversion/libsvn_client/merge_elements.c` line 112 in latest source (1.14.0). In the comment, it states,

> Perform a three-way tree merge. Write the result to *MERGE_RESULT_P.
> Set *CONFLICTS_P to describe any conflicts, or set *CONFLICTS_P to null if there are none.