# Which is more suitable on Windows, git or mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial

I actually use a combination of OS X, Linux and Windows, but Windows is the most important.

Comment: Visual SourceSafe! *(Ducks and runs...)*

Comment: @T.J.: Does VSS work on OS X or Linux?  I'd expect "no," but figured I'd ask.  @Zubair: Do you prefer command-line or GUI tools?

Comment: *whoosh*...Damn! I missed. He ducked.

Comment: @Mike: It was a joke. (God, I *hope* the upvoters were upvoting as humorous, not informational!) If I were seriously suggesting it, I'd've used an answer (and not ducked and run). :-)

Comment: I would prefer command line AND gui tools

Comment: @Zubair: *"I would prefer command line AND gui tools"* It looks like answer is: Either, it's up to you. Both work, both have both command-line and GUI tools available. You might be interested in this question; actually, yours is pretty much a duplicate (not criticizing): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161541/svn-vs-git

Comment: A comparison between Subversion and Git is the same thing as a comparison between Mercurial and Git? ... Mercurial and Subversion aren't really interchangeable in this context... Another joke, or a bad day?  And, yeah, you had me worried there with VSS (which I have never used).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git was initially designed without much regard for use on Windows. Mercurial was built to be multi-platform from the start. This gave Mercurial an edge over Git on Windows, but as far as I've heard, the difference is [mostly or completely gone](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and you might consider other criteria to base your choice on.

FWIW, I haven't seen any problems using Mercurial on GNU/Linux and WinXP.

Comment: Yeah, I use `git` on Windows without any trouble. I'm a command-line guy, but apparently there's even a Windows Explorer plug-in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit

Comment: Hg has an explorer plug-in, too: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/.  That's why I'm wondering if this question is git vs. hg or TortoiseGit vs. TortoiseHg...

Comment: TortoicseGit 1.0.2.0 has a better UI than TortoiseHg 0.7. While those are relatively old versions, the situation's now far better for Git on Windows than it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Both work for me, but I use Win2K. One thing I have noticed is that the very latest version of Mercurial (1.5) is NOT supported on Win2K, and in fact will not install. The 1.4 relase works fine. This has kind of put me off using Mercurial at all, as it really is not on to drop support for an OS at a minor release, without any explanation.

Comment: To be fair to the Mercurial folks, Microsoft only supports Win2k until July: http://support.microsoft.com/ph/1131

Comment: Was the drop intentional?  Win2K is 10 years old; it's getting hard to find hardware it runs on.  Or maybe the hg dev with the 2k box quit... ^_^

Comment: @Mike Everyone else seem sto be managing to support it, including git and svn.

Comment: Which is why it sounds unintentional, especially if they haven't said anything about it.

Comment: @Neil, I'll try the TortoiseHg 1.0 (Hg 1.5) installer on my Win2k VM when I get home tonight, and submit a bug report based on what happens. Hg/Thg normally say when something has been actively deprecated, so I doubt this was intended.

Comment: Please see (and contribute to) this thread: http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/bmwvbhzd76awgolr  Dropping Windows 2000 support is only a matter of lack of an environment to test in, and the man-power to do it. We have (to my knowledge) not begun using anything which is not supported on Windows 2000 and I would encourage people to step forward and make installers for it. I'm sure you can still find all the scripts and whatnot online, otherwise please ask on the mailinglist.