# Simple Version Contol

Tags: version-control

We work on a lot of small website projects. There are three of us in different physical locations. I would like a system that is very simple where the main concern is checking out and checking in web files (php, css, images, js) so that we don't accidentally overwrite each other's code. We also need a way to synch our local file systems with the files on the webserver and with each other. Rolling back to older versions is nice but features like branching and merging are not important. It seems like GIT may be overkill for our purpose or maybe not. Can you recommend anything?

Comment: I don't think git is overkill at all. Or svn. They should be simple enough to get setup and running, and since they're popular you'll find lots of plugins for all your IDE's and lots of tutorials and support in general. And if things grow, better to have chosen a proven system than something else.

Comment: Git or any other system are as overkill as you would like them to be. Just use the commands you feel are necessary.

Comment: GIT is powerful, but never overkill. It does as much or as little for you as you want. I cannot find enough good words for it, and I find it hard to imagine how you could go wrong with GIT. Check out the "Network" and "Fork queue" features on GitHub to get a taste of the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with either SVN or Git.

- Both have good tools and IDE support
- Both can be used later on if really you need branching and merging

If you start with source code management you should probably use SVN. For many new developers it seems easier to understand that there is only one main directory (trunk) and everybody has the same version.

You can always switch to Git later on. There are very good tools out there to convert SVN repositories to Git repositories.

On the long run you will save yourself some headaches with a good source control management tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [Svn vs Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161541/svn-vs-git) for some useful information.

Personally, I prefer SVN's ability to only checkout what you want to, but either should be easy enough to set up and use.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people like svn for it's similarities with a real filesystem, and using trunks as branches, etc, and others prefer git for it's powerful functionality.  I personally prefer git, but the learning-curve can be a little daunting, and I routinely force VCS' into submission as part of my job.
converting from svn to git (or any other VCS) is going to be difficult, and you're likely to be forced to make compromises that you hadn't anticipated.
As an alternative, you might like Mercurial.  I'm not really a fan, but it has most/all of git's power with a much friendlier interface. It is easily as popular as the other two, and is probably going to be the least painful to convert to git, later, due to the common heritage.