# Remove a magento theme - Rollback to default

Tags: magento

This is my first time working with Magento and here is what happend: I spent two days reading the documentation and tweaking the settings to fit my needs. I then installed this theme:

http://themeforest.net/item/decostore-magento-theme/1876494?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.seg_1=category_thumb&WT.z_author=8theme

The problem is that the theme didn't work the way I was expecting and now I'd like to rollback to the default theme and completely remove everything added by this theme to my installation.

Unfortunately, I didn't backup the installation and database before I installed the new theme and I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 to using version control as mentioned below. My biz uses github. It's annoying at first but really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Switching back to default theme**

Go to the admin area and then `system > configuration > design`

Change "Current Package Name" to 'default' and make sure all inputs under the "Themes" section are empty.  This will return you to the default theme.

**2. Completely remove everything added by this theme**

I take it from your question that you are not using any form of source control.  Might be an idea to look into this for the future :)

Magento 1.7 has introduced backup and rollback features so you may also want to check that out.

**If this is the case, backup everything before you start removing files and directories as described below**

Anyway, to completely remove all files and directories added when you installed the module, unfortunately it will simply be a case of manually finding the files and directories deleting.

The easiest way to do this will be to find the original source code you received when you purchased the theme and removing the corresponding files from your site.  **When removing directories be careful to only remove those specific to the theme**  - It will have been sent to you structured so that you can easily drag straight in to your web root - so will contain some other directories required by Magento, simply to give it the correct hierarchy.

At the very least there will be files and folders specific to the theme located in the following directories:

- app/design/frontend
- skin/frontend
- js

and also most likely some more in the following:

- app/etc/modules
- app/design/adminhtml
- app/locale

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation. I change the settings on the admin and I can see the default theme now. I will go ahead and try to remove the files. As for this "source control thing", do you recommend anything in particular (open source or free tool)?

Comment: SVN and GIt are popular choices  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161541/svn-vs-git

Answer (score 0):

I know the result for this can be different for everyone, but in case someone else comes across my specific case, it was the N98 folder under app/code/community/N98 that caused the problem. Particularly their CustomerGroupCheckout plugin as shown here: https://github.com/amenk/N98_CustomerGroupCheckout

Removing the N98 folder brought back the configuration page.