# Restore Magento Admin Panel layout

Tags: admin, magento-1.9

Installed [bubble admin theme](https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-admin-theme.html) on my Magento store, it worked well.
However deactivated it to use the default theme and this(screen shots) is the layout I get. Have cleared all caches, tried overwrite the admin files with fresh files from a Magento package but still no change. Tried reactivating and reinstalling the admin theme, no much difference. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T47mn.png)

Can I restore the default admin panel layout? Have done so much modifications since my last backup. Will really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the following link. It seems like this is a similar if not the same issue and it has been answered there.

Visit [Remove a magento theme - Rollback to default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172377/remove-a-magento-theme-rollback-to-default)