# what is diffrence between GIT and Tortoise Repository?

Tags: repository

I am new to this forum but i found very quick responce from active developers.

i have query with technical diffrence between "GIT" and Tortoise "SVN". if any one has work on it please give me detail description.

thanks
tousif shaikh.

Comment: Maybe redundant to http://stackoverflow.com/a/161572/1758762

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean surely a difference between Git and svn? Tortoise is just a GUI for (mostly) svn.
Take a look at this wiki article: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSvnComparison
or at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/161572/1758762 :

SVN is one repo and lots of clients. GIT is a repo with lots of client repos, each with a user. It's decentralised to a point where people can track their own edits locally without having to push things to an external server.

SVN is designed to be more central where GIT is based on each user having their own GIT repo and those repos push changes back up into a central one. For that reason, GIT gives individuals better local version control.

and so long ...

Comment: The wiki article you refer to has many mistakes. Make sure to read these comments http://svnvsgit.com/ before looking through this wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

SVN workflow:

- The trunk directory represents the latest stable release of a
  project.
- Active feature work is developed within subdirectories under branches
- When a feature is finished, the feature directory is merged into
  trunk and removed.

Git workflow :

- A Git repository stores the full history of all of its branches and
  tags within the .git directory.
- The latest stable release is contained within the master branch.
  Active feature work is developed in separate branches.
- When a feature is finished, the feature branch is merged into master 
  and deleted.