# Not able to push to Github, getting "permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: git, ssh, public-key, github-for-windows

```
Administrator@SANZVAIO /e/projects/pySan (master)
$ git remote add pySan git@github.com:sanfx/.git

Administrator@SANZVAIO /e/projects/pySan (master)
$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of know
n hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any other way to push to github? I am using Git Bash on Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402281/github-push-error-permission-denied and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026796/git-repositiory-adding-files

Comment: Have you uploaded your [ssh key to github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)?

Comment: yes srikanth, this fix the problem, but now i am getting this 

`$ git push git@github.com:sanfx/pySan.git
Enter passphrase for key '/e/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa':
To git@github.com:sanfx/pySan.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:sanfx/pySan.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: It's just that: Your local branch is "behind" the remote branch, so you cannot push until you pull (update) your local branch.

Git is a very powerful tool, that actually enhances your development. Please read this excellent guide on Git: http://git-scm.com/book/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You repo URL is wrong
2. You might also have an SSH issue.

You should first create an empty repository on GitHub, via [the webinterface](https://github.com/new) or the [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

Let's suppose you have just created `myrepo`, the URL syntax to use is:

```
git remote add pySan git@github.com:sanfx/myrepo.git
```

If you still have SSH errors, either check your public/private keypair, or use https to start out:

```
git remote set-url pySan https://github.com/sanfx/myrepo.git
```

Comment: anyway i figured it out , first i had to set up the SSH key correctly for this windows login, then I had to use this command `git push -f  origin <branch name> ` and I am on path to be gitorious...