# Multiple Build Agents - TeamCity - VisualSVN Server - ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, svn, continuous-integration, teamcity, visualsvn-server

I am thinking about setting up TeamCity with 2 build agents. One being our staging server with will be an exact copy of our development version and updated on every SVN/GIT commit. And the other would be our live server which would only update manually and wouldn't copy over certain files (web.config for example).

Is this setup possible? I have done this before using a combination of CCNet and MSBuild, but it was very fiddly.

On the standard version of TeamCity you can have 20 integrations, is that 20 active integrations (old ones can be switched off or would I need to delete the old ones and re-add them if needed).

And finally I have always been an SVN man, but I hear about and see people using GIT more and more, is it any better or am I fine just carrying on with SVN.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need more agents for this scenario. All you need is more build configurations. One will deploy on your staging server triggered by each commit and second to deploy on your production environment on push button.

Comment: Thanks, Would I do the deployment using MSBuild or can TeamCity move the "artifacts"? (Don't know if this is the right term...)

Comment: Also am I best using MSBuild or is there a better way now? The last time I did and CI was about 3-4 years ago and I am guessing things have changed.

Comment: I'm using MSBuild for packaging and MsDeploy for deployment to server. Orchestrated by [simple Psake script](https://gist.github.com/579086), but you can use what you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is certainly possible with TeamCity. If you've already done this with CC.NET and MSBuild, it should be straightforward to call your MSBuild script from TeamCity. TeamCity [supports MSBuild out of the box](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/MSBuild). BTW, the term that JetBrains uses for what you are talking about is "configurations". "Build agents" are for [supporting multiple/simultaneous builds](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/the_build_grid.html).

For your question regarding SVN vs Git, do a search and you'll find plenty of resources, but here are a few highlights:

- [Why is Git better than Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35074/im-a-subversion-geek-why-i-should-consider-or-not-consider-mercurial-or-git-or
- http://docs.joomla.org/Dvcs