# Get the date of the most recent entry (file or directory) within a directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a bunch of directories with different revisions of the same c++ project within. I'd like to make things sorted out moving each of these directories to a parent directory named by pattern of `YYYY.MM.DD`. Where `YYYY.MM.DD` is the date of the most recent entry (file or directory) in a directory.

How can I recursively find the date of the most recent entry in a particular directory?

#### Update

Below is one of the ways to do it:

```
find . -not -type d -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Or even:

```
find . -not -type d -printf "%TY.%Tm.%Td\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: "I have a bunch of directories with different revisions of the same c++ project within". Have you considered using source control system? I recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Yes, We are using `SVN` for the newer projects. Thanks anyway! Is it worth to switch to `Git`? Does `Git` have any of significant advantages over `SVN`?

Comment: I prefer Git. Unfortunately the Git vs SVN debate is off-topic for StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/871/78845

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ls -t|head -n 1` to list files sorted by modification date and show only the first. The date will be in the format defined by your locale (ie YYYY-MM-DD).

For example,

> `ls -tl | awk '{date=$6; file=$8; system("mkdir " date); system("mv $8 " " date"/")'`

will go through all files and create a directory for every modification data and move the file there (beware: care must be taken for filenames containing whitespace). Now use `find -type d` in the root directory of the source tree to recursively list all the directories. Combined with the above you have now (sadly there is some overhead now):

> `for dir in $(find -type d) ; do
>   export dir
>   ls -tl dir| awk '{dir=ENVIRON["dir"]; date=$6; file=$8; system("mkdir " dir "/" date); system("mv " dir "/" $8 " " dir "/" date"/")'
>   done`

This does not go recursively through the tree, but takes all directories of the complete tree and then iterates over them. If you need the date-directories outside of the source tree (suppose so), just edit the two system() calls in the awk script accordingly.

**Edited: fix script, add more description**

Comment: Are there any chances to force these scripts to do recursive search?

Comment: find does a recursive search. You could, in fact, accept the answer of @choroba, mine is 'slightly' convoluted I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, mixing your solution with the previous answer:

```
find -print0 | xargs --null ls -dtl
```

It shows directories as well.

Comment: Useless use of xargs. There is an `-exec` option in `find`.