# How to checkout GitHub submodule from SVN

Tags: github, svn, git-submodules, svn-checkout

I am pretty new to GitHub.
  I need to check out several packages of code to build my system, most of them are on SVN. However, there is one which is on GitHub. Within this there is a submodule inside it.
My question is how to check out this submodule by using `svn co ...`

I list all components by editing

```
svn propedit svn:externals
```

Among them one is on GitHub. I can check out all components except that submodule.

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
svn checkout https://github.com/user/repo
```

Comment: Some short explanation would be helpful here.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. The command I mentioned is to clone the whole repo. For just a part of it, I don't know. Try checking [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233327/is-it-possible-to-clone-only-part-of-a-git-project)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `git`, not `svn`. Git and Subversion (SVN) are fundamentally different; Here's a [pretty good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion), and here's some [pretty good documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation).

The command you will want is:

`git clone <url>`

Where URL is the URL give when you hit the 'Clone or Download' button shown when you browse to the repository in Github.

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is to build the system in one shot by doing "svn co .....". At this time I can checkout the solid part of code in github by "svn co ....", but the submodule can't be checkout. I think this is because submodule is a link, rather than solid body. So I am looking for help to see if anyone had this kind of problem before. This is the situation I am facing.  -- Jim

Comment: @Jim perhaps [this](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/) addresses your need? I gather that you want to checkout a directory using `svn` from GitHub, which can be done using the link and AFAIK usual SVN practices. If this isn't sufficient then you'll need to explain why before I can offer much else :).

Comment: Liam: Say I have a git repository xyz, inside this it has directory a, b, and c. Note c is a submodule. If I do "svn co https://gitgub.com/..../xyz", I can only check out directories a and b, not c. This is my situation. I can checkout them using git command but my work requires me to use svn to check out this. Thanks.  -- Jim